# Identificar Dual Sim Card no Android

Tags: android

Estou tentando identificar sim card no smartphone Galaxy Y porém, esse smartphone é dual chip e não consigo exibir. Dei uma pesquisada mais só achei como identificar apenas um sim card

```
 TelephonyManager telMgr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
 telMgr.getLine1Number()
```

Não existe um método `telMgr.getLine2Number()`

Comment: De uma olhada nessa pergunta e a primeira resposta no StackOverflow EN: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14517338/android-check-whether-the-phone-is-dual-sim/17499889#17499889. Pelo visto você terá que partir para `Reflection`.

Comment: Vixe, reflaction é um Deus nos acuda. Prefiro aderir a essa solução http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5255147/dual-sim-card-android

Comment: Ah, se a samsung tiver uma API para esse dispositivo não tem problema, mas não tem muita solução além de Reflection se for fazer algo mais genérico.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static boolean isMultiSim() {
    int slotCount = 1;
    try {
        slotCount = (Integer) Class.forName("com.android.internal.telephony.MultiSimManager")
                .getDeclaredMethod("getSimSlotCount").invoke(null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("TAG", "Error trying to get sim slot count", e);
    }
    return slotCount > 1;
}
```

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/30168/101

Answer (score 0):

Acho que isso resolve o seu problema

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

import android.content.Context;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;

public final class TelephonyInfo {

    private static TelephonyInfo telephonyInfo;
    private String imeiSIM1;
    private String imeiSIM2;
    private boolean isSIM1Ready;
    private boolean isSIM2Ready;

    public String getImeiSIM1() {
        return imeiSIM1;
    }

    /*public static void setImeiSIM1(String imeiSIM1) {
        TelephonyInfo.imeiSIM1 = imeiSIM1;
    }*/

    public String getImeiSIM2() {
        return imeiSIM2;
    }

    /*public static void setImeiSIM2(String imeiSIM2) {
        TelephonyInfo.imeiSIM2 = imeiSIM2;
    }*/

    public boolean isSIM1Ready() {
        return isSIM1Ready;
    }

    /*public static void setSIM1Ready(boolean isSIM1Ready) {
        TelephonyInfo.isSIM1Ready = isSIM1Ready;
    }*/

    public boolean isSIM2Ready() {
        return isSIM2Ready;
    }

    /*public static void setSIM2Ready(boolean isSIM2Ready) {
        TelephonyInfo.isSIM2Ready = isSIM2Ready;
    }*/

    public boolean isDualSIM() {
        return imeiSIM2 != null;
    }

    private TelephonyInfo() {
    }

    public static TelephonyInfo getInstance(Context context){

        if(telephonyInfo == null) {

            telephonyInfo = new TelephonyInfo();

            TelephonyManager telephonyManager = ((TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE));

            telephonyInfo.imeiSIM1 = telephonyManager.getDeviceId();;
            telephonyInfo.imeiSIM2 = null;

            try {
                telephonyInfo.imeiSIM1 = getDeviceIdBySlot(context, "getDeviceIdGemini", 0);
                telephonyInfo.imeiSIM2 = getDeviceIdBySlot(context, "getDeviceIdGemini", 1);
            } catch (GeminiMethodNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

                try {
                    telephonyInfo.imeiSIM1 = getDeviceIdBySlot(context, "getDeviceId", 0);
                    telephonyInfo.imeiSIM2 = getDeviceIdBySlot(context, "getDeviceId", 1);
                } catch (GeminiMethodNotFoundException e1) {
                    //Call here for next manufacturer's predicted method name if you wish
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            telephonyInfo.isSIM1Ready = telephonyManager.getSimState() == TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_READY;
            telephonyInfo.isSIM2Ready = false;

            try {
                telephonyInfo.isSIM1Ready = getSIMStateBySlot(context, "getSimStateGemini", 0);
                telephonyInfo.isSIM2Ready = getSIMStateBySlot(context, "getSimStateGemini", 1);
            } catch (GeminiMethodNotFoundException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

                try {
                    telephonyInfo.isSIM1Ready = getSIMStateBySlot(context, "getSimState", 0);
                    telephonyInfo.isSIM2Ready = getSIMStateBySlot(context, "getSimState", 1);
                } catch (GeminiMethodNotFoundException e1) {
                    //Call here for next manufacturer's predicted method name if you wish
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        return telephonyInfo;
    }

    private static String getDeviceIdBySlot(Context context, String predictedMethodName, int slotID) throws GeminiMethodNotFoundException {

        String imei = null;

        TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

        try{

            Class<?> telephonyClass = Class.forName(telephony.getClass().getName());

            Class<?>[] parameter = new Class[1];
            parameter[0] = int.class;
            Method getSimID = telephonyClass.getMethod(predictedMethodName, parameter);

            Object[] obParameter = new Object[1];
            obParameter[0] = slotID;
            Object ob_phone = getSimID.invoke(telephony, obParameter);

            if(ob_phone != null){
                imei = ob_phone.toString();

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new GeminiMethodNotFoundException(predictedMethodName);
        }

        return imei;
    }

    private static  boolean getSIMStateBySlot(Context context, String predictedMethodName, int slotID) throws GeminiMethodNotFoundException {

        boolean isReady = false;

        TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

        try{

            Class<?> telephonyClass = Class.forName(telephony.getClass().getName());

            Class<?>[] parameter = new Class[1];
            parameter[0] = int.class;
            Method getSimStateGemini = telephonyClass.getMethod(predictedMethodName, parameter);

            Object[] obParameter = new Object[1];
            obParameter[0] = slotID;
            Object ob_phone = getSimStateGemini.invoke(telephony, obParameter);

            if(ob_phone != null){
                int simState = Integer.parseInt(ob_phone.toString());
                if(simState == TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_READY){
                    isReady = true;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new GeminiMethodNotFoundException(predictedMethodName);
        }

        return isReady;
    }


    private static class GeminiMethodNotFoundException extends Exception {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = -996812356902545308L;

        public GeminiMethodNotFoundException(String info) {
            super(info);
        }
    }
}
```

Veja o fonte completo neste link, com edições:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14517338/android-check-whether-the-phone-is-dual-sim

Comment: Testei essa solução mais não funcionou pra mim, basicamente só reconheceu um único sim card, acredito que seja o nome do método de identificação do simcard2 da Samsung que está errado.