# Há algum inconveniente em sempre capturar Exception e não algo mais específico?

Tags: java, exceção

Quando escrevo código em Java e tento tratar excepções costumo usar simplesmente a superclasse `Exception`, não ligando à classe específica e costuma resultar. Há algum inconveniente em fazer isto?

```
try{
    Integer i = Integer.parseInt("3")
} catch(Exception e){ //em vez de NumberFormatException

}
```

Answer (score 68, accepted):

De um modo geral, não faz sentido você capturar uma exceção se você não pretende tratá-la. O ideal seria deixá-la "borbulhar" (*bubble*) para o código chamador mesmo, até que se encontre algum método que seja de fato capaz de tratá-la.

Java possui essas "exceções checadas" (*checked exceptions*), que te obrigam a ou tratar ou declarar na assinatura do método que você pode lançá-las. Por conta disso, muita gente acaba fazendo coisas como:

```
catch(Exception e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

Pra não ter que ficar declarando "throws isso", "throws aquilo" em tudo quanto e método. Isso não é uma boa prática, pois no final as mensagens de erro que são impressas no console/logadas em arquivo ficam desnecessariamente grandes e confusas - isso quando não são truncadas...

Se você tem um código "top-level" - tipo o método `main`, ou o `run` de um thread, ou um ouvinte (*event listener*) do Swing, etc - que *não pode* lançar exceções de jeito nenhum, não há problema na minha opinião em se usar um `catch` genérico, se sua única ação possível naquele momento é logar/imprimir o erro e abortar a execução. Caso contrário, prefira capturar a exceção específica que você vai tratar. Se você pretende tratar da mesma forma de um conjunto de exceções, também não há problema em se capturar seu tipo mais geral.

Mas se você quer dar um tratamento "personalizado" para uma exceção - digamos exibir "entre com um número" quando encontra um `NumberFormatException` - usar `catch Exception` pode acabar mascarando um outro erro que não tem nada a ver, deixando o usuário irritado pelo programa reclamar do formato quando sua entrada está correta, e tornando mais difícil a depuração pois a causa real da exceção se perdeu (se você a deixar borbulhar, no mínimo ela vai ser impressa/logada no final).

Comment: Poderia definir "borbulhar"?

Comment: @Patrick Digo que a exceção borbulha quando ela não para naquele método, mas sobe pro método chamador. Potencialmente subindo para o chamador do chamador, e assim por diante, até que ela seja tratada ou chegue no *top level*.

Comment: Normalmente, não tenho por onde deixar mais borbulhar. Tenho k tentar que o programa não pare, simplesmente. Obrigado pelo esclarecimento

Answer (score 36):

Boa parte do que poderia lhe responder aqui pode ser achada na resposta [Como melhor tratar exceções em Java?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21933/101). Lá tem diversos *links* para outras respostas que se lidas em conjunto dá um bom entendimento do problema que tratamento de exceção se tornou na programação (eu sei, é muita coisa mas é de extrema importância entender o assunto). Embora alguns *links* não se refiram ao Java a ideia geral é a mesma.

A primeira coisa que você deve se perguntar é o que você ganha capturando a `Exception`. Por que você faz isto? Deve haver um motivo. Ele é usado para trazer melhores resultados? Ou ele é usado porque parece ser mais fácil, ou porque muita gente faz desse jeito?

Eu imagino que você saiba que uma exceção nunca deva ser "engolida". No seu exemplo isto acontece mas acredito que seja apenas um exemplo simplificado. Se não sabia disto, talvez esta seja a informação nova para você mais importante deste *post*. Vamos ver o exemplo com uma ação no `catch`, assim a exceção `NumberFormatException` não é completamente engolida (embora a ação realizada na captura não ajude muito em caso real):

```
try {
    Integer i = Integer.parseInt("3")
} catch(Exception e){ //em vez de NumberFormatException
    System.out.println("Número inválido");
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Exception/CaptureException.java).

O problema está resolvido? Deixou de existir o *engolimento* de exceção? Não! E pior, você nem está percebendo que está engolindo exceções. Engole sem querer. Se existir um erro de alocação de memória sua aplicação vai quebrar dizendo que houve um `Número inválido`. E você vai se perguntar porque diabos isto aconteceu. Você engoliu todas as outras exceções possíveis. Você capturou todas as exceções possíveis e deu tratamento para apenas uma delas.

E se der o tratamento para todas elas, resolve? Pode parecer que sim. É o que você deseja fazer? Em um simples problema, você deseja se preocupar com qualquer exceção possível? Você consegue saber todas elas? Elas serão estáveis, ou seja, nunca surgirão novas que tornarão sua aplicação menos robusta? Mesmo que o faça, o que você ganhou com isto?

Então vamos olhar para uma situação mais provável em aplicação real. Olhemos para a situação demonstrada na resposta do Lucas Polo. Ali pode ocorrer diversas exceções. Tentar tratar todas como se fosse a mesma coisa cai no mesmo problema.

Imaginemos um problema ainda mais complicado. Você chama um método, não sabe o que faz (mesmo que saiba não ajuda muito) e que pode ser modificado sem você saber. Ele pode ter muito mais exceções. Poderá ter exceções causadas por erros de programação que você estará capturando e dizendo que existe apenas um `Número inválido` quando o problema é bem mais sério. Pode haver erros de *runtime* (de verdade) como acessos a recursos (arquivos, redes, DBs) que falham e que definitivamente não são números inválidos.

Se você der sorte (ou azar) vai usar uma API que usa *checked exception* e saberá o que **deve** tratar (capturando ou delegando explicitamente). Aí você captura a `Exception` e "trata" o que a API exige. "Trata" todas as exceções que são obrigatórias dando uma solução única que muito provavelmente não resolve o problema real.

Mesmo no seu exemplo simples pode não parecer tão complicado tratar todas as exceções individualmente, mas aí no futuro precisa colocar novas operações dentro do `try` e esquece de cuidar de todas as novas exceções possíveis. Virtualmente qualquer coisa que você faz em um programa pode disparar uma exceção.

Exceção é um controle de fluxo extremamente complicado. Muito mais complicado que o [`goto` que todo mundo já entendeu que é complicado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/20874/101). **Ela vem de onde você nem imagina** ([artigo do Joel Spolsky sobre isto](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2003/10/13.html)).

## Regra básica

Só trate uma exceção que você **sabe especificamente** o que fazer com ela. Se você quer tratar um `NumberFormatException`, dê o tratamento para a `NumberFormatException`. Se você vai tratar um `FileNotFoundException`, trate dela e não faça outras coisas. Se você pode tratar todas as exceções que são `IOException` da mesma forma, ok, esta é a mais específica e ela pode ser tratada. E é claro que você pode tratar da `Exception` quando ela é a mais específica possível. Isto em geral só ocorre em métodos "altos" da aplicação, o `Main()`, por exemplo. Em geral a única coisa a se fazer neste caso é avisar o usuário e registrar o erro (*log*) para um profissional analisar.

Se você não sabe o que fazer com cada uma das exceções que está capturando, não capture. A captura apenas irá mascarar o que está acontecendo. Se não pode resolver o problema deixe ela propagar para um nível mais alto. Isto vale especialmente para exceções causadas por erros de programação. Estes erros precisam ser consertados pelo programador, não há outra coisa a fazer. Capturar exceções sem querer escondem erros de programação.

## Por que você usa `Exception`?

A impressão que eu tenho é que dá uma falsa sensação de segurança capturar todos os problemas possíveis. Mas em programação sempre que você tenta resolver alguma coisa que não sabe o porquê, ou "por via das dúvidas", acaba cometendo um erro. Alguns só deixam o código mais sujo, outros causam problemas reais.

Para concluir, o exemplo final do Lucas Polo é bom até que ele resolve capturar a `Exception` ali mesmo (notar que a Oracle não recomenda isto). Tudo bem, é só um exemplo fictício postado aqui mas se for usado em produção estará tratando a exceção "por via das dúvidas". Provavelmente está descentralizando e duplicando um mesmo tratamento em vários pontos da aplicação. Procure no seu código para ver se não há duplicações no tratamento.

Claro que pode ser que você tenha que fazer algo específico ali mesmo para todas as exceções, mas isto é extremamente raro. Normalmente o tratamento de `Exception` só é útil no `Main()` ou outro ponto de entrada, no método que controla todo um *framework* (de UI, por exemplo), ou em uma *thread*.

- Não engula exceções, principalmente sem querer.
- Não misture exceções não relacionadas.
- Não trate o que não pode ser tratado, mesmo sem querer.
- Use o pensamento "toda vez que eu capturar uma `Exception` eu não sei o que está acontecendo com meu programa".

Esta última vale até quando usa esta captura no `Main()`. Mas tudo bem, neste caso é normal que você não saiba. Quando capturar uma exceção ali é fundamental ter registrado todos os detalhes da exceção, assim você pode descobrir que poderia ter capturado uma exceção mais específica em outro local e tratar melhor. Mas aí você tem uma informação concreta que a captura é necessária.

Comment: Como *sidenote*. Infelizmente o Java acabou se apaixonando pelo "um mecanismo resolve tudo" e exceções são usadas extensivamente para tratar fluxo normal da aplicação. Mas isto é outro problema que trato nos outros posts sobre o assunto. Acompanhe no link que eu forneci acima.

Comment: Essencialmente eu programo para correr em android. E no Thread da UI toda a excepção não tratada vai fazer a app crashar. Pelo que muitas vezes vou pelo geral, porque, não sei o que mais pode sair de um metodo, mesmo que isso dificulte a depuração do erro :/

Comment: Não conheço especificamente o *framework* e UI que você está usando e até faz algum sentido ter **uma** captura de `Exception` na *thread* da UI para fazer a captura final antes da aplicação quebrar. Em geral em captura serve para pegar os erros de programação, inclusive os erros de esquecimento de ter capturado algo que merece a captura em outro lugar, que não deixa de ser um erros de programação. Por sorte (ou azar, é discutível) em Java as exceções importantes você será obrigado tratar próximo do erro mesmo (mas deve tratar de forma específica). Quanto mais você engole exceções sem querer..

Comment: ... mais você terá dificuldade de se entender com exceções, mais sua aplicação vai ficar imprevisível. Se você não sabe o que capturar e o que fazer para **resolver** a falha, não capture! Eu sei que é bastante coisa para ler mas nos links contidos na minha resposta apontada no começo desta são fundamentais para você entender melhor o funcionamento e os problemas de capturar exceções do jeito errado. Quando começar usar exceções da forma correta sua vida vai melhorar muito. Pergunta coisas mais específicas se ainda precisa entender mais coisas mas pare de sofrer :)

Comment: Essa resposta não só é útil como também comove e faz as pessoas abandonarem hábitos ruins. Se pudesse dava +2.

Answer (score 28):

Caso no seu trecho de código seja disparada apenas uma exception, não vai fazer muita diferença, mas se no mesmo trecho for possível ser lançada mais de uma, você não poderá dar um tratamento específico. A melhor abordagem é deixar um tratamento para cada tipo e caso queira agrupar, desde o Java 7 você pode fazer desta forma:

```
public class ExampleExceptionHandlingNew
{
   public static void main( String[] args )
   {
    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://www.yoursimpledate.server/");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
        String line = reader.readLine();
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/DD/YY");
        Date date = format.parse(line);
    }
    catch(ParseException | IOException exception) {
        // handle our problems here.
    }
   }
}
```

Desta forma fica mais simples de agrupar, e caso seja necessário, você pode fazer uma abordagem mais específica para cada exceção e no final, caso alguma passe direto, você pode capturar Exception para casos não esperados:

```
public class ExampleExceptionHandlingNew
{
   public static void main( String[] args )
   {
    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://www.yoursimpledate.server/");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
        String line = reader.readLine();
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/DD/YY");
        Date date = format.parse(line);
    } catch(ParseException exception) {
        // handle our problems here.
    } catch(IOException exception) {
        // your code
    } catch(Exception exception) {
        // 
    }
   }
}
```

Tem mais aqui neste [link da Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/java7exceptions-486908.html), onde eu também peguei o exemplo.

Comment: Gostei da segunda parte, pois o cara trata as exceções conhecidas e se cair na última pelo menos ele já sabe que não foi nenhuma das duas anteriores.(+1)

Answer (score 2):

Especificar ou generalizar o tratamento da exceção vai depender muito do que a aplicação precisa. Imagine um sistema muito grande e que o erro será exibido na tela do usuário. Como você vai saber que ponto atacar se você não sabe de onde vem o erro? É erro da aplicação ou erro de massa de dados? O usuário vai reportar o erro pra equipe de desenvolvimento ou vai corrigir sua entrada de dados? O que vai ser apresentado na tela vai te dar o direcionamento do que fazer. Use o bom senso. Lembre que uma parte de desenvolvimento é criando a aplicação e a outra é mantendo.

Answer (score -1):

A ideia seria você saber exatamente o erro que a aplicação está gerando para trata-lo de forma adequada.

Quando uma aplicação gera mais de um erro na mesma parte fica mais nítido o porque é importante usar to try, catch dessa forma.

Outra coisa que não comentaram foi o finally que é um trecho de código que sempre será executado independente da exceção, e mesmo se não houver uma exceção esse código será executado. Ficaria assim:

```
try{

}catch(Exception e){

}finally{

}
```