# Qual a diferença entre "throw" e "throw ex"?

Tags: c#, .net, exceção, throw

Vi que o C# permite fazer...

```
try
{
    //algum código
}
catch
{
    throw;
}
```

também...

```
try
{
    //algum código
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
```

e...

```
try
{
    //algum código
}
catch (Exception)
{
    throw;
}
```

Minhas dúvidas são: para onde a exceção é jogada no `throw`, qual a diferença entre as três e se houver alguma, qual a melhor situação para usar cada uma?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Os exemplos primeiro e último na prática são idênticos se você estiver usando só C# como linguagem na sua aplicação. Não especificar o que capturar indica que está capturando `Exception`. Ou seja, qualquer exceção. Existe uma diferença em um caso.

Se você estiver usando C++ ou outra linguagem que permite lançar qualquer coisa (uma *string*, um número, uma estrutura de dados qualquer) e mandar o C# capturar esta exceção, vai funcionar no primeiro exemplo. Como ele não especifique o que pegar, pega qualquer coisa. Mas não funcionará no último exemplo, afinal você está especificando que quer exceções do tipo `Exception` e, é claro, todas as exceções herdadas direta ou indiretamente da `Exception`.

O C# só permite lançar exceções deste tipo e suas derivadas. Então um `catch` sem especificação pegará qualquer exceção lançada pelo C#, que é o mesmo que um `catch (Exception ex)`.

Você sempre deve usar `throw;`.

Quando você emite um `throw ex;` você está parando a exceção ali fazendo alguma operação (no seu caso nem isto está feito mas vou considerar que é apenas para ser um exemplo) e depois lança **outra** exceção dali em diante. Ele perde a informação de onde veio realmente original a exceção real e lança uma **nova**. É como se tivesse ocorrido um problema novo. Dificilmente existirá um caso onde isto é desejável. No seu exemplo você provavelmente capturará uma exceção mais específica e lançar uma `Exception` que é a exceção que você capturou e muito geral que não é desejável (eu respondo muito sobre isto, minha resposta mais recente sobre o assunto é a [Há algum inconveniente em sempre capturar `Exception` e não algo mais específico?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/30168/101), lá tem um *link* para outras respostas).

Emitindo apenas o `throw;` você está repassando a **mesma** exceção para frente, então outro trecho do código (onde existe um `catch`) poderá capturar e saber o que fazer com a exceção original preservando todas informações necessárias, principalmente o *stack trace*.

Sempre que você lança uma exceção ela vai parar onde achar o primeiro `catch`. Embora raro, isto pode ser logo no mesmo método que a exceção foi lançada, pode ser no método chamador, pode ser no método anterior, e o anterior a ele e assim vai, até que pode ser no `Main()` e até mesmo se não encontrar um `catch` em lugar algum vai cair em um `catch` implícito "escondido" pelo ambiente. Quando você lança um *throw* não dá para ter certeza onde ele será capturado a não ser que seja uma aplicação muito pequena desenvolvida só por você e não costuma acrescentar coisas novas nela.

O único lugar que uma exceção para é um `catch` (claro que um `finally` não deixa de ser um `catch`. Eu diria que isto é válido para qualquer linguagem, pelo menos é para todas que eu conheço.

Note que se você usar o código apresentado na pergunta em código real ele não faz nenhum sentido. Não tem porque você capturar uma exceção, não fazer nada com ela e repassá-la pra frente para outro `catch` tomar alguma providência.

Achei um [exemplo no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/776756/221800) que ajuda entender melhor:

```
using System;
using static System.Console;

public class Program {
     public static void Main(string[] args) {
        try {
            ThrowException1(); // line 19
        } catch (Exception x) {
            WriteLine("Exception 1:");
            WriteLine(x.StackTrace);
        }
        try {
            ThrowException2(); // line 25
        } catch (Exception x) {
            WriteLine("Exception 2:");
            WriteLine(x.StackTrace);
        }
    }

    private static void ThrowException1() {
        try {
            DivByZero(); // line 34
        } catch {
            throw; // line 36
        }
    }

    private static void ThrowException2() {
        try {
            DivByZero(); // line 41
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw ex; // line 43
        }
    }

    private static void DivByZero() {
        int x = 0;
        int y = 1 / x; // line 49
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/FftK9S). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/SCCT7Z). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Exception/Retrow.cs).

A saída seria:

> ```
> Exception 1:
>    at UnitTester.Program.DivByZero() in <snip>\Dev\UnitTester\Program.cs:line 49
>    at UnitTester.Program.ThrowException1() in <snip>\Dev\UnitTester\Program.cs:line 36
>    at UnitTester.Program.TestExceptions() in <snip>\Dev\UnitTester\Program.cs:line 19
>
> Exception 2:
>    at UnitTester.Program.ThrowException2() in <snip>\Dev\UnitTester\Program.cs:line 43
>    at UnitTester.Program.TestExceptions() in <snip>\Dev\UnitTester\Program.cs:line 25
> ```

Notou que o segundo com `throw ex;` perdeu uma informação importante de onde realmente a exceção ocorreu? E aí você fica como "barata tonta" tentando achar alguma coisa em um método. Claro que pode parecer fácil achar o erro mas lembre-se que este é um código simples de exemplo, pode ser que você perca vários níveis de chamadas de métodos, que os métodos sejam mais complexos.

Código CIL gerado quando usa um `throw ex;`:

```
catch [mscorlib]System.Exception {
    IL_000b:  stloc.0
    IL_000c:  nop
    IL_000d:  ldloc.0
    IL_000e:  throw
}
```

E com `throw;`:

```
 catch [mscorlib]System.Exception {
    IL_000b:  stloc.0
    IL_000c:  nop
    IL_000d:  rethrow
 }
```

A instrução real a ser executada é bem diferente. O primeiro código lança uma exceção de uma forma normal usando como argumento o que estiver na pilha e o segundo faz uma operação completamente diferente. Explicitamente está **re**lançando a exceção ativa (note que não é carregado nenhum argumento com a instrução `ldloc` como é feito no exemplo anterior).

Comment: O que seria esse "para frente"? Eu sei que no Java ele joga a exceção para o método que está chamando (`throws`), seria isso aqui também?

Comment: Depois do almoço eu vou dar uma melhorada mas esse "pra frente" é mais ou menos o que você está dizendo, embora mesmo no Java ele não precisa parar no método chamador, ele pára quando encontrar um `catch`, mesmo que seja o `catch` implícito que toda aplicação tem "escondida" se você não prover nenhum `catch` na sua. Lembre-se sempre que o único lugar que uma exceção pára é um `catch` e nem sempre é fácil prever onde vai parar. Por isso não deve-se abusar de exceções. É um `goto` longo e imprevisível.

Comment: Eu costumo jogar todas as exceções para view, para reportar ao usuário a partir de lá.

Comment: Normalmente é uma boa. Se fizer direito. Para falar a verdade mesmo o `throw;` raramente é necessário usar. Tem sua utilidade mas em geral quando você captura a exceção e faz tudo o que precisa fazer com ela, não é tão comum "borbulhar" a exceção pra outro `catch` capturar e tantar fazer algo. Uma exceção seria você tentar se recuperar, não conseguir e aí relançar a **mesma** exceção para a sua *view* dar uma apresentação final para seus usuário.