# Manter stack trace quando o método dá rethrow na exception capturada

Tags: c#, .net, exceção, log, recuperação-de-erros

Executei em uma aplicação o Code Analysis do Visual Studio e em vários métodos recebi a seguinte mensagem:

> CA2200    Rethrow to preserve stack
>   details   'fooBLO.FooMethod(DadosProjetoDTO, string)' rethrows a caught
>   exception and specifies it explicitly as an argument. Use 'throw'
>   without an argument instead, in order to preserve the stack location
>   where the exception was initially raised. BLL FooBLO.cs   143

**Método exemplo:**

```
public bool CadastrarSolicitacao(DadosProjeto oDadosProjeto, string tipoProcesso)
{
    try
    {
        //Método que também utiliza Exception causando o "rethrows"
        GeraSolicitacao solicitacao = PreencherGeracao(oDadosProjeto);

        //Outras tratativas do método......
        //..........

        //Método que também utiliza Exception causando o "rethrows"
        return _interfaceDAO.CadastrarSolicitacao(solicitacao);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        //Aqui utilizo o exception em "e" para gravar o log do erro (e.Message)
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Entendi que nesse método eu recebo o alerta pois tanto o método `PreencherGeracao` quanto o `CadastrarSolicitacao` que são chamados por ele já tem um `throw` e no método de exemplo `_interfaceDAO.CadastrarSolicitacao` ele tem a possibilidade de dar outro `throw` sendo que este pode ter sido enviado de um dos método chamados por ele, e dessa forma perco o rastreamento.

O próprio Code Analysis orienta a usar apenas o `throw` sem o argumento. Essa realmente é a melhor prática?

O argumento ainda estou usando para gravar o log de erro do sistema. Estou ciente que isso muitas vezes causa a gravação de mais de um *log* de erro, pois se o método `PreencherGeracao` der `Exception` ele irá gravar um *log* e o método de exemplo também. Isso é uma má pratica? Eu deveria gravar o *log* apenas na última camada?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim é melhor usar `throw` do que `throw e` porque assim não destrói o *stack trace* e dá melhor informação sobre o erro, mas talvez o correto mesmo é nem ter esse `try-catch`.

Se precisa *logar* todo erro sem fazer nada a mais, nada específico, isto deveria ser feito em outro local. Se vai fazer algo específico é lá que deveria *logar*. [Quase sempre capturar `Exception` é um erro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/30124/101), incluindo esse caso.

Talvez esteja [usando exceção onde não deve](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/13611/101). Talvez seja o caso de [outra solução](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21767/101). E [veja mais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21933/101) e [também](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15261/101).

Leia [Qual a diferença entre "throw" e "throw ex"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/34181/101). Talvez seja duplicata, só vi agora no final.