# Acesso Negado ao salvar imagem em uma aplicação

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight

Fiz um aplicativo Silverlight que captura imagem usando a web cam. O aplicativo funciona perfeitamente porém quando vou salvar a imagem capturada gera o seguinte erro:

> File operation not permitted. Access to path: 'D:\Web....' is denied

Stack Trace:

> em System.IO.FileSecurityState.EnsureState() em System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost) em System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost) em System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare >share) em SilverlightCam.WebCam.SalvarImagem(FrameworkElement bitmap) em SilverlightCam.MainPage.BtSalvar_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)

A pasta D:\Web contém todas as permissões e ainda quando rodo a aplicação fora do navegador (Out-of-browser) consigo salvar na pasta sem problemas.

O método que salva a imagem é este:

```
public void SalvarImagem(FrameworkElement bitmap)
{            
 String filename = @"D:\Web\" + MakeFileName();
 using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create,   FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Write))
 {                
   BitmapSource source = GetBitmapSource(bitmap);
   PngBitmapEncoder encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();

   encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(source));
   encoder.Save(stream);
   stream.Close();                
 }            
}
```

O método 'MakeFileName' gera um nome aleatório para a imagem a ser salva:

```
internal static String MakeFileName()
{
  int index = 0;
  bool uppercase = false;
  String filename = String.Empty;
  String caracters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890";

  Random random = new Random();

  for (int i = 0; i < caracters.Length; i++)
  {
   uppercase = Convert.ToBoolean(random.Next(0, 2));                
   index = random.Next(0, caracters.Length);

   filename += uppercase == true ? Char.ToUpper(caracters[index]) : caracters[index];                
  }    

 return String.Format("{0}.{1}", filename, "png");
}
```

Por sua vez o método 'GetBitmapSource' renderiza a imagem no componente:

```
internal static BitmapSource GetBitmapSource(FrameworkElement element)
{
 ScaleTransform scale = new ScaleTransform() { ScaleX = 1, ScaleY = 1 };            
 Size size = new Size(element.ActualWidth, element.ActualHeight);

 WriteableBitmap bitmap = new WriteableBitmap((int)size.Width, (int)size.Height);
 bitmap.Render((element as UIElement), scale);
 bitmap.Invalidate();

 return (bitmap as BitmapSource);
}
```

Eu chamo a função da seguinte maneira:

```
private void BtSalvar_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
 try
 {
  WebCam.SalvarImagem(ImageCam);
  lblMsg.Content = "Imagem Salva com Sucesso!";
 }

 catch (Exception ex)
 {
  lblMsg.Content = ex.Message;
  txtLog.Text = ex.StackTrace;
 }
}
```

**ImageCam** é um componente **Image** onde armazeno a imagem capturada. 
Qualquer ajuda é bem vinda

Comment: Achei que a *tag* Silverlight nunca seria criada :) Uma dica já que você gosta de capturar `Exception`: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/30124/h%C3%A1-algum-inconveniente-em-sempre-capturar-exception-e-n%C3%A3o-algo-mais-espec%C3%ADfico/30168#30168 vai seguiindo os links, tá cheio de postagens sobre o assunto.

Comment: Interessante esse artigo, eu usei uma Exception 'genérica' por não saber como capturar o erro gerado. Como vim do Java fiquei mal acostumado com o Netbeans/Eclipse me falando qual exceção tal método lança.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você não pode acessar o sistema de arquivos local em uma aplicação Silverlight diretamente - se fosse o caso, um site poderia ter um controle silverlight escondido numa página, e teria acesso ao sistema de arquivo de qualquer pessoa que visitasse o site. Para acessar o sistema de arquivos, o usuário precisa dar permissão à aplicação SL para tal, e isso pode ser feito de duas formas;

- Unstalar a aplicação localmente: fazendo isso o usuário indica que "confia" na aplicação
- Usar um [`SaveFileDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.savefiledialog(v=vs.95).aspx), onde o usuário tem que escolher que arquivo será gravado.

O código abaixo mostra uma forma de implementar a segunda opção:

```
public void SalvarImagem(FrameworkElement bitmap)
{
    SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
    sfd.Filter = "Arquivos PNG|*.png|Todos os arquivos|*.*";
    sfd.DefaultExt = ".png";
    var result =sfd.ShowDialog();
    if (result.HasValue && result.Value) {
        using (stream = sfd.OpenFile())
        {                
            BitmapSource source = GetBitmapSource(bitmap);
            PngBitmapEncoder encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();

            encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(source));
            encoder.Save(stream);
            stream.Close();                
        }            
    }
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado! Funcionou aqui. Agora como eu faria para instalar a aplicação localmente?

Comment: Instalar localmente = rodar fora do navegador (out of browser), o que você já conseguiu fazer, segundo a sua pergunta.

Comment: Entendi. Ainda sou iniciante no mundo do Silverlight