# Como usar um try catch dentro de outro?

Tags: php, exceção, try-catch

Preciso gravar dados em um banco de dados, e caso ele tenha sucesso, então irei gerar um `.pdf` com o PHP.

Mesmo que eu coloque um `try catch` em uma parte do código e ele der o `exception`, ainda assim o resto do código será executado. Seria ruim eu colocar um `try catch` dentro de outro? Caso não, qual seria uma opção válida sem matar nenhuma boa prática? Usar um `if` para verificar se `$bancoDeDados` não está vazio?

## Meu Código

```
try {
    $bancoDeDados = new Bd();
    $bancoDeDados->createCreateEntidade($valor1,$valor2);
    try {
        $this->geraPdf($valor1,$valor2);
    }
    catch(ExceptionSeiLa $e) {
    }
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
}
```

## O que preciso

Preciso que esse geração de PDF só ocorra se o insert for bem sucedido.

Comment: Você pode dar um exemplo do que seria esse bloco de guarda de do outro? Esqueça boas práticas, tudo pode ter serventia ou não de acordo com a situação específica. Este seu exemplo parece ser adequado (se considerar que é apenas um exemplo) mas ele não tem `try` aninhado. Eu falo bastante sobre o uso e abuso de exceções. Não falo especificamente sobre PHP mas pode ler várias respostas que ajudam entender melhor este mecanismo tão mal usado. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/30124 (vai seguindo os links nela e nas outras linkadas nela).

Comment: Esse try-catch dentro do outro tá parecendo questão da certificação da Zend que derrete seus miolos :P

Comment: Da uma olhada na resposta dessa pergunta [Para que servem os Blocos Try/Catch e quando devem ser utilizados?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/58536/para-que-servem-os-blocos-try-catch-e-quando-devem-ser-utilizados/424523#424523)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Cada caso é um caso, mas em geral aninhamento de `try` não é o mais adequado. Isto provavelmente indica que está capturando mais exceções do que deve.

De qualquer forma, normalmente você quer apenas dar um tratamento para a exceção. `try catch` **não é um controle de fluxo normal**, por isso raramente faz sentido tê-los aninhados. O lançamento de uma exceção é um *long jump*, ou seja, ele vai para um local distante, possivelmente desconhecido. Então não importa tanto assim onde está o `catch`, ele pode, e é muito comum, que nem esteja na função atual. Isto é o normal.

O importante quando uma exceção é lançada é que ela seja capturada por algum `catch` em algum lugar do código da sua aplicação, qualquer lugar que seja adequado capturar e fazer algo útil para tentar se recuperar do erro. Não se preocupe com o fluxo, ele já será "desvirtuado" do seu normal após o `throw`.

Esta captura pode ser única em todo o sistema, só para *logar* o erro e apresentar de forma "bonita" para o usuário. Não abuse de captura de erros. Veja mais sobre isto em [outras respostas minhas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/30168/101). É importante notar que usar um `catch` não faz milagres, ele não resolve problemas por si só. Pelo contrário, seu exagero faz esconder erros.

Então no seu exemplo o "mais correto" seria:

```
try {
    $bancoDeDados = new Bd();
    $bancoDeDados->createCreateEntidade($valor1,$valor2);
    $this->geraPdf($valor1,$valor2);
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    //faz alguma coisa
}
catch(ExceptionSeiLa $e) {
    //faz alguma coisa
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura.](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Syntax/NestedTryCatch.php)

Se der um problema de `PDOExcption` quando chamar o `Bd()` ou o `createCreateEntidade` ele vai desviar para o primeiro `catch`. Se ocorrer a `ExceptionSeiLa`, provavelmente gerada pelo método `geraPdf`, o desvio será para o segundo `catch`.

Um `catch` não precisa e, em geral, não deve estar associado a um `try` exclusivo. Você deve tratar todas as exceções que precisa tratar neste momento de forma enfileirada, e não uma por vez de forma aninhada.

Claro que **pode** existir alguma situação que o aninhamento seja útil. Mas é extramente raro.

Se for gerada uma exceção antes de executar o `geraPdf()`, provavelmente pelo `Bd()` ou o `createCreateEntidade`, certamente ele não será executado, a exceção gera um desvio antes de chegar nele e faz o que você deseja. Dependendo do que você quer, talvez até o segundo `catch` seja desnecessário.

Mas evite abusar da captura de exceções que você não pode fazer nada útil. Eu entendo que você fez apenas um exemplo simples, mas se capturar uma exceção e não fizer nada com ela, algo está errado.

Pessoalmente se eu posso evitar o uso de exceção, eu o faço. Se eu puder verificar com `if` se há algo errado, eu o faço. Só uso exceção se:

- o algoritmo com `if` ficar mais confuso que com o `try catch`
- pode gerar uma *[race condition](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/159342/101)* ou perda considerável de performance
- a API obriga fazer isto (não existe outra forma disponível de "pegar" o erro).

Este último caso é muito comum em Java. A cultura e o ambiente da linguagem incentivam o uso de exceções.

Não tenho muito experiência com as APIs novas do PHP, mas o que eu sempre usei do PHP, exceções raramente são necessárias. Sempre tem uma forma de resolver a questão sem o seu uso. Mas o PHP começou sem exceções se dava muito bem sem elas. Claro que sua adição trouxe novas perspectivas mas também trouxe muito abuso.

Você ainda pode cair nos dois primeiros casos. No primeiro pode ser mais vantajoso preferir a exceção e no segundo pode ser obrigatório para ter a solução correta e com performance adequada.

Comment: Simplesmente excelente. Muito obrigado pela ajuda ! Você não tem ideia de como fiquei esclarecido.