# Como mover arquivos lidos por StreamReader em C#?

Tags: c#, .net, arquivo, stream-de-arquivos

Estou tentando mover alguns arquivos. Para cada arquivo contendo a palavra "TESTE" em seu corpo, o meu aplicativo indica sendo um item encontrado. O objetivo é movê-los para um outro diretório. Segue o código abaixo:

```
string[] Lista = new string[] { "TESTE"};

string dir = @"C:\ORIGEM";
string dir2 = @"C:\DESTINO";

private void btnQuarentena_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   List<string> busca= Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();                  
   foreach (string item in busca)
   {                                              
     StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(item);
     string ler = stream.ReadToEnd();
            foreach (string st in Lista)
            {
              if (Regex.IsMatch(ler, st))
              {
                try
                        {                            
                            stream.Close();
                            stream = null;
                            GC.Collect();
                            File.SetAttributes(dir, FileAttributes.Normal);
                            File.Move(item, dir2);

                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            lblvirus.Text = "Alguns arquivos não puderam ser movidos! " + ex;
                        }
              }                             
            }
   }
}
```

Como percebe-se, o método *stream* dentro de meu *try catch block* foi desativado, para não haver erros de processo. O Visual Studio me retorna um erro de acesso não autorizado, e não trata-se de um diretório de acesso ao volume do sistema ou não autorizado. O teste foi realizado também com dispositivos de armazenamento removível, e o mesmo erro ocorre, sendo:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>   Additional information: Acesso negado ao caminho.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tem vários erros aí. Primeiro eu acho que você deveria ler de outra forma mais simples. Mas vou seguir a sua linha.

Nunca use `GC.Collect` a não ser que você saiba muito bem o que está fazendo e tenha domínio de todas as implicações. Você está destruindo a organização do *heap* fazendo isto.

Nunca capture uma exceção que você não sabe bem para que. E nunca capture mais do que deve. Principalmente não capture a `Exception`. Veja esta [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/30168/101) para aprender sobre exceções. Vai seguindo todos os links da resposta e os links contidos nas outras que você for seguindo. É importante. Eu sei, é bastante texto para ler, mas é fundamental que você entenda como usar exceção. Alguns textos eu falo sobre Java mas não se preocupe, em C# é bem parecido, e a maioria dos links vai levar para respostas específicas sobre C#.

Você está cometendo dois erros clássicos. Tenta mandar o GC coletar lixo porque sua aplicação está vazando memória. Conserte o vazamento. Coletar lixo não vai resolver seu problema. Está tentando "esconder" um erro que vai acontecer. `try catch` não foi feito para fazer de conta que não nenhum erro aconteceu, foi feito para capturar erros que você sabe como tratar. Se não sabe como resolver ele, deixe a outra parte da aplicação lidar com o erro, até mesmo quebrar a aplicação.

O `dir2` é apenas um *path* simples, e o parâmetro ali deve ser um *path* completo. Você terá que montá-lo antes de passar como argumento através do [`GetFileName()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getfilename?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=netcore-3.1#System_IO_Path_GetFileName_System_String_) e [`Path.Combine()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=netcore-3.1#System_IO_Path_Combine_System_String_System_String_).

Tem mais algumas coisas que a solução não é a ideal mas não vou interferir porque não é o foco da pergunta.

O que você precisa fazer: ler o arquivo, achar o que procura, marcar que achou, fechar o arquivo e mover. Eu não pude testar ainda mas mais ou menos seria o seguinte:

```
string[] Lista = new string[] { "TESTE"};

string dir = @"C:\ORIGEM";
string dir2 = @"C:\DESTINO";

private void btnQuarentena_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    List<string> busca= Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();
    foreach (string item in busca) {
        var achou = false;
        //abre o arquivo "garantindo" seu fechamento no final do escopo
        using (var stream = new StreamReader(item)) {
            var arquivo = stream.ReadToEnd();
            foreach (var texto in Lista) {
                if (Regex.IsMatch(arquivo, texto)) {
                    achou = true;
                    break; //se achou não precisa mais continuar procurando
                }
            }
        }
        if (achou) {
            //não se esqueça que o using "garantiu" o fechamento do arquivo
            File.Move(item, Path.Combine(dir2, Path.GetFileName(item)));
        }
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura.](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/IO/Pattern.cs)

Se ainda achar que deve capturar uma exceção para colocar a mensagem em `lblvirus.Text` mas capture no local certo e somente a exceção específica, no máximo a `IOException` mas preferencialmente uma mais específica.

Comment: Obrigado, mas infelizmente não funcionou. Ocorreu o mesmo erro.

Comment: Você já experimentou mover o arquivo pura e simplesmente, sem fazer nada com ele? Parece que seu problema é de permissão no sistema operacional.

Comment: Não, mas eu consigo apagá-lo. Se houverem outros arquivos no diretório de origem que não contenham a palavra "TESTE" dentro de seu corpo, estes são ignorados, sendo apagados somente os que contenham a mesma. Por essa lógica, talvez não seja um problema de permissão. Vou fazer o teste, não custa tentar.

Comment: Tentou substituir por `FileInfo.MoveTo()`?

Comment: Agora que eu percebi que o `dir2` é apenas um *path* simples, e o parâmetro ali deve ser um *path* completo. Estou achando que vai ter que montá-lo antes de passar como argumento.

Comment: Funcionou. Realmente o que faltava era combinar o diretório, da forma que você editou. Muito obrigado, tem me ajudado muito até agora @bigown!