# Como fazer o retorno de 2 variáveis de uma função

Tags: java, exceção, return, método

Estou a aceder a um *webservice*, que tem como retorno:

`listProdutos[]` -> Lista de todos os produtos ou `null` quando não existe produtos

Quando perde o acesso por algum motivo, lança uma excepção, e nesse caso preciso de fazer o retorno de uma segunda variável (flag) que me informe se esse problema ocorreu ou não:

Código exemplo:

```
    Public listProdutos[] boolean getProdutosWS(String prod){
    boolean flag=false
    try{
       listProdutos[] produtos = ws.getProdutos(prod)
       flag=true
       return produtos, flag;
    }catch(RemoteException ex){
       return null, flag=false;

    }
}
```

Como solucionar este problema?

Comment: Reserve a posição 0 do retorno para a flag.

Comment: Qual é a estrutura da classe `listProdutos`?

Comment: é composta por 3 strings || construtores || get's e set's (dá para perceber!?)

Comment: Se há uma exceção, você deveria propagar ela, esta não é a forma correta de lidar com isto. Se quiser insistir acredito que a melhor forma é criar uma classe só para isto (já que o Java não dá muitas facilidades) cujos membros será esta lista de produtos e a *flag*, aí no retorno você desestrutura a classe, ou seja, pega cada um dos membros e usa como quiser (joga em variável, usa em `if`, etc.).

Comment: @bigown eu já estive a pesquisar sobre isto e vi essa opção, mas pareceu me um pouco estranha(criar uma classe só para isso!?) podias explicar melhor isso de propagar a excepção? eu tentei fazer o catch aonde pretendo mas nao consegui

Comment: @jsantos1991 concordo com você que é estranho mas é a solução se quiser insistir no erro. Pelo menos em Java não vejo outra forma de resolver isto. Insisto que você deve resolver isto deixando a exceção transbordar para o método que sabe como tratar o problema adequadamente. O que você está tentando fazer é mais estranho ainda. Veja [essa resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/30168/101) que eu dei e vai seguindo **todos** os links dela e das outras que for seguindo para aprender mais sobre exceção (vale até o que não é sobre Java).

Comment: @jsantos1991 Você não é obrigado a propagar exceção de comunicação. Releve cautelosamente esta recomendação de que você "deve" propagá-la. A forma como você está tentando fazer não é necessariamente um erro.

Comment: @jsantos1991 leia tudo o que eu te passei e depois você me diz se você ganha alguma coisa lidando com a exceção antes do momento que pode fazer algo com ela e transformá-la em *flag*. Se você ganhar alguma coisa de verdade, se conseguir mostrar que tem uma justificativa plausível, vá em frente, caso contrário, você está fazendo *over engineering*. **Nunca trate uma exceção quando você não pode fazer nada útil com ela**. Isto é regra básica do uso de exceção.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Se há uma exceção, você deveria propagar ela e deixar que outro método lide com o problema, esta não é a forma correta de lidar com isto. Você vai ter que lidar com o problema, fazer do jeito certo ou errado.

Se quiser insistir, acredito que a melhor forma é criar uma classe só para isto (já que o Java não dá muitas facilidades) cujos membros será esta lista de produtos e a *flag*, aí no retorno você desestrutura a classe, ou seja, pega cada um dos membros e usa como quiser (joga em variável, usa em `if`, etc.).

Note que eu discordo de cada linha dessa solução mas seria algo mais ou menos assim (os códigos não estão prontos para uso, é só uma ideia geral):

```
public class Resultado {
    public boolean flag; //não faça isto, fiz só para simplificar
    public listProdutos[] produtos; //prefira usar métodos de acesso get e set
    public Resultado(listProdutos[] produtos, boolean flag) {
        this.produtos = produtos;
        this.flag = flag;
    }
}

public Resultado getProdutosWS() {
    try{
        listProdutos[] produtos = ws.getProdutos(prod)
        return new Resultado(produtos, true);
    }catch(RemoteException ex){
        return new Resultado(null, false);
    }
}

public static main() {
    Resultado lista = getProdutosWS();
    if (lista.flag) {
        System.out.println(lista.produtos[0]); //isto é só um exemplo de uso, nada que seja útil
    }
}
```

Quanto mais eu olho para isso mais eu acho estranho. Eu acho que você deveria tratar a exceção, por esse exemplo, no `main`, algo como:

```
public AlgumMetodoConsumidor(TipoDoWS ws, TipoDoProd prod) {
    try {
        listProdutos[] lista = ws.getProdutos(prod)();
        System.out.println(lista); //isto é só um exemplo de uso, nada que seja útil
    } catch (RemoteException ex) {
        //regra básica das exceções: você lida aqui com o problema porque é
        //aqui que você consegue lidar com ele.
        System.out.println("deu erro");
    }
}
```

Alternativa para não ter que criar uma classe específica para isso. A vantagem seria que a classe `Resultado` seria usado para todo local que precisa retornar uma *flag* além de um outro retorno:

```
public class Resultado {
    public boolean flag; //não faça isto, fiz só para simplificar
    public Resultado(boolean flag) {
        this.flag = flag;
    }
}

public Resultado getProdutosWS(Resultado resultado) {
    try{
        listProdutos[] produtos = ws.getProdutos(prod)
        resultado.flag = true;
        return produtos;
    }catch(RemoteException ex){
        resultado.flag = false;
        return null;
    }
}

public static main() {
    Resultado resultado;
    listProdutos[] lista = getProdutosWS(resultado);
    if (resultado) {
        System.out.println(lista[0]); //isto é só um exemplo de uso, nada que seja útil
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Method/ReturnTwoValues.java).

Por outro lado, não sei se não bastaria verificar se a lista é `null`. Claro, depende da situação.

Comment: Propagar ou não a exceção é uma decisão de design - não é possível fazer uma única recomendação que atenda todos os casos. Quando um método entrega dados obtidos de um webservice, é muito comum não querer propagar exceção de comunicação. Nestes casos, este método pode escolher simplesmente retornar uma coleção vazia. O uso de flag de sucesso também não está descartado.

Comment: @Caffé tens razão mas neste caso o que eu queria fazer era mesmo propagar a excepção, tinha tentado fazer isso mas sem sucesso, mas com os links do bigown felizmente percebi o significado do `Throws` assim adicionei ao cabeçalho da função, e aonde ia receber o `return` como ja faço o `try...catch` já não preciso de receber os dois valores

Comment: @bigown se poderes postar um exemplo do uso do throws ou de como propagar a excepção poderia marcar a tua resposta como certa, eu já tenho o meu problema a funcionar é só mesmo para a tua resposta ficar completa...

Comment: @jsantos1991 já faço já, deixa só eu terminar uma coisinha aqui. Se bem que já coloquei o segundo exemplo que é mais ou menos o que você precisa. Porque se eliminar a *flag* desnecessária, parece que todo o método `getProdutosWS` passa ser desnecessário.

Comment: @bigown sim compreendo o que quer dizer, e na verdade é, de certa forma, porque assim consigo separar toda a comunicação do webservice com o resto do programa(possivelmente está errado) mas é como sei fazer... Só queria deixar claro que a solução foi de adicionar o `Throws` na função e tratar da excepção no nível de cima

Comment: Na verdade o `Throws` ajuda você ser obrigado a tratar no método chamador mas ele não é obrigatório. Você experimentou sem usar ele? Não estou dizendo para você tirar, apenas adicionando a informação que é possível fazer sem a cláusula `Throws`. A cultura do Java é usar onde for útil.

Answer (score 5):

Em Java, quando você quer que uma função retorne múltiplos valores, você deve:

- adicionar esse valores em um objeto e então retorná-los
- ou alterar um objeto que é passado para a função

No seu caso, você precisa claramente definir uma classe `mostrar` que poderia ter campos necessários.

```
public class Mostrar {
    private boolean flag = false;
    private List<String> produtos = null;

}
```

então retorna o seu objeto

```
return new Teste(flag, produtos) ;
```

Answer (score 3):

Não é uma resposta propriamente dita. Mas uma questão de sugestão. Aqui vai a minha:

```
class ListProdutos{
    private boolean isFlag = false;
    public boolean getIsFlag(){ return isFLag; }
    // Construtor sobrecarregado definindo um objeto flag.
    // Supondo que o seu outro construtor tem parâmetros.
    // Esse construtor não faz mais nada, apenas define o flag. 
    public ListProdutos(){
        isFlag = true;
    }
     //Resto da classe...
}
```

A solução propriamente seria criar um campo `isFLag` e sobrecarregar um construtor pra criar um objeto *flag*.

Supondo que possam existir vários tipos de erro, você pode posteriormente adicionar um campo `public String flag;` com a descrição do erro.

Comment: Mas daí você muda o contexto da lista de produtos para atender um problema de design do código.

Answer (score 3):

Não é possível ter mais de um retorno em um método Java. Em .Net usamos parâmetros de saída, mas Java não possui isso também.

Você terá que criar um design diferente para a sua solução.

Uma opção é retonar um objeto complexo:

```
// encontre um nome mais significativo 
// para esta classe e seus atributos
class Resultado {

    Produto[] listProdutos;
    boolean requestSucesso;
}

Public listProdutos[] getProdutosWS(String prod){
    Resultado resultado = new Resultado();
    try{
        resultado.listProdutos[] produtos = ws.getProdutos(prod)
        resultado.requestSucesso = true;
        return resultado;
    }catch(RemoteException ex){
        resultado.requestSucesso = false;
        return resultado;
    }
}
```

Outra opção é não fazer o tratamento de exceção aí mas sim no consumidor de `getProdutosWS`. Neste caso, o consumidor não verifica um flag mas apenas acredita que, se não houve exceção, o método retornou o que precisava.

E uma terceira opção é implementar dois métodos nesta classe atualmente publica o `getProdutosWS`. Um método indica se houve sucesso na requisição e outro método retorna os produtos.