# Passando parâmetro null para um método

Tags: java, parâmetros, null, nullable

É possível passar/receber parâmetros nulos no Java.

No C# eu sei que é possível utilizando `?` no tipo.

```
public DateTime Teste(DateTime? exemplo){...}
```

Neste caso o exemplo sei que pode vir `null`, no Java isso é possível de alguma maneira?

Comment: Funciona da mesma forma, mas se atribuires o valor de "exemplo" a alguma coisa dentro da função vai te lançar uma exceção.

Comment: @JorgeB. Responda a pergunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se você tiver usando os tipos primitivos (`int`, `boolean`, `long`, `char`, etc.) no parâmetro, então você não pode passar `null` para uma função:

```
public java.util.Date Teste(boolean valor) { ... }
public void Test2() {
    Test(null); // erro de compilação
}
```

Se você quiser usar um tipo "nullable", você deve usar a classe correspondente ao tipo primitivo do parâmetro:

```
public java.util.Date Teste(Boolean valor) { ... }
public void Test2() {
    Test(null); // funciona
    Test(false); // funciona também
}
```

Note que no seu exemplo, a classe correspondente a DateTime em Java é `java.util.Date` (entre outras opções) que não é um tipo primitivo, então você pode passar `null` diretamente sem problemas.

Comment: Obrigado, deu certinho.

Answer (score 2):

Entendo que você está falando para fazer isto para tipos primitivos. Todas as classes do Java aceitam nulos como no C#. Em Java apenas os tipos primitivos não aceitam nulo, assim como normalmente ocorre com os `ValueType`s do C#.

O C# arrumou uma solução encapsulando esses tipos em uma `struct` chamada `Nullable`. Nela consta o dado que você está trabalhando e uma * flag* indicando se é nulo ou não, afinal tipos por valor não podem ter valores excepcionais, então é necessário uma informação extra. E foi criada a sintaxe do `Tipo?` que no fundo é traduzido para `Nullable<Tipo>` quando compila.

Há duas soluções para Java:

1. Usar `Integer`. Ele é uma classe, ele pode ter uma referência nula. Algo assim:

   ```
    Integer inteiro = MetodoQualquer();
    if (inteiro  == null) {
        // faz algo
    } else {
        // faz outra coisa
    }
   ```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Typing/Null.java).

2. É possível simular isto criando uma classe que contenha um *flag* indicando a condição de `null` e o valor propriamente dito. É uma forma muito semelhante ao que dei [nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/39314/101) (evidentemente que não teria o tipo primitivo e não uma lista). Ou seja, você está reproduzindo o que o `Nullable` do C# faz. Mas não tem o açúcar sintático do `Tipo?` que o C# tem. Não é uma solução tão boa porque o Java não tem `structs` (*value types*) definidos por usuário, mas resolve.

Ainda existe a opção de usar a anotação `@Nullable` mas acredito que não faz exatamente o que você espera.

Não citei o exemplo do `DateTime` porque ao contrário do C# em Java este tipo é por referência, por isto aceita `null` naturalmente.