# Lista de erros exception do PHP

Tags: php, exceção

Onde posso encontrar uma lista com os códigos de erros de *exceptions* do `try catch` em PHP?

Comment: Exceções foram criadas justamente para não precisar disto. Não há como. Você pode criar uma exceção nova. Um módulo adiciona novas exceções, uma atualização pode disponibilizar novas exceções à qualquer momento. A minha lista seria diferente da sua. Você provavelmente está pedindo isto por não conhecer como funciona o recurso. Para aprender um pouco mais pode ler http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/30124/h%C3%A1-algum-inconveniente-em-sempre-capturar-exception-e-n%C3%A3o-algo-mais-espec%C3%ADfico/30168#30168. Vai seguindo todos os links, é importante. Não é sobre PHP mas a base é a mesma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pode ser pego o código da `Exception` sim, diferente com o @Maniero disse acima.

vou postar um exemplo simples mostrando como:

```
<?php
    try{
        $x = rand(0,15);
       
        if($x > 1 AND $x <=10){
            echo "O valor está entre 1 e 10";
        } elseif ($x == 0){
            throw new Exception("O valor não está na faixa adequada. Valor gerado : $x", 999999);           
        }
    } catch(Exception $e){
        $debug = array(
            'Mensagem' => $e -> getMessage() ,
            'Código'    => $e -> getCode()
        );
        
        print_r($debug);
    }
?>
```

Retornará:

```
 se $x = 1 a 10 : "O Valor está entre 1 e 10"
 caso contrário : "O valor não está na faixa adequada. Valor gerado : $x";
```

[Você pode verificar mais detalhes no php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.exception.php).

Comment: Entendo que o código mencionado pode servir pra se obter a mensagem da _exception_, (o que pode ser uma boa solução para o problema do autor da pergunta). Só uma observação: o comentário a que você se referiu é sobre existir uma lista com esses códigos, e de fato o comentário procede.

Comment: Realmente não existe uma lista. Vai ter que ir por 'tentativa-error-documentação' conforme vai aparecendo conforme foi dito.

Comment: @DouglasDreer não cheguei a pensar desta forma, mas era isso mesmo que eu queria, saber o que cada código representa de erro, muito obrigado!

Answer (score 4):

Exceções foram criadas justamente para não precisar de uma lista. É para ser desestruturado e descentralizado mesmo. Você sabe quais as exceções podem acontecer estudando a documentação da API específica que está usando.

Não há como fornecer uma lista. Você pode criar uma exceção nova. Um módulo adiciona novas exceções. Uma atualização pode disponibilizar novas exceções à qualquer momento. A minha lista seria diferente da sua.

E outro ponto importante, não basta saber quais exceções podem ocorrer. Se você não sabe o que fazer com ela, você não deve capturá-la. Claro que é possível capturar qualquer exceção (capturando a `Exception` que é a exceção mais genérica). Mas quase sempre é um erro fazê-lo porque a única coisa que você pode fazer com certeza com ela é apresentar o erro de uma forma mais bonitinha para o usuário e talvez mandar para um sistema de *log*. Não dá para tratar nada de forma mais específica em algo tão genérico.

Você provavelmente está pedindo isto por não conhecer como funciona o recurso. Para aprender um pouco mais sobre o assunto pode ler [essa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/30168/101). Vai seguindo todos os links, é importante. Não é sobre PHP mas a base é a mesma.

Leia mais na [documentação oficial do PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php). Sobre a [classe Exception](http://php.net/manual/en/class.exception.php). Um [bom tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php-exceptions--net-22274) em inglês.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).