# Quebra de linha em mensagem de e-mail

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, string, email

Na minha `string mensagem`, eu gostaria de ter um espaço de duas linhas, já tentei usar o "/n" e não obtive o resultado esperado.

```
@{
    var customerName = Request["customerName"];
    var customerEmail = Request["customerEmail"];
    var customerRequest = Request["customerRequest"];
    var customerSubject = Request["customerSubject"];
    var atendimento = "teste@teste.com.br";
    var errorMessage = string.Empty;
    var debuggingFlag = false;
    string mensagem = string.Format(customerRequest + "\n\n{0}", customerEmail);
    try
    {
        // Initialize WebMail helper
        WebMail.SmtpServer = "smtp.teste.com.br";
        WebMail.SmtpPort = 25;
        WebMail.UserName = "teste@teste.com.br";
        WebMail.Password = "teste";
        WebMail.From = "teste@teste.com.br";

        // Send email
            WebMail.Send(to: atendimento,
                subject: customerSubject + " - " + customerName,
                body: mensagem
            );
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        errorMessage = ex.Message;
    }
}
```

Comment: tenta utilizar `\n\r`, sua mensagem é `text/plain?` Se estiver como text/html pode utilizar a tag `<br/>`.

Comment: @claudsan o octeto usado deve ser `\r\n`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Environment.NewLine`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.newline?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=netcore-3.1#System_Environment_NewLine) ao invés de `\n`. É o correto. Estou considerando que está usando o *default* para [`MailMessage.IsBodyHtml`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.mailmessage.isbodyhtml?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=netcore-3.1#System_Net_Mail_MailMessage_IsBodyHtml). Caso contrário a solução passar por colocar um `<br/>`.

Não capture `Exception`. Veja mais sobre o assunto acompanhando todas as respostas que eu já dei começando por [essa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/30168/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: O Enviroment.NewLine não serviu, pois é a mesma coisa que "/r/n" senão estou enganado, porém o <br/> serviu, li a sua resposta que me indicaste, muito bom, evitarei usar Exceptions, e pegarei o costume de fazer a pergunta "Por que usar Exception aqui?"

Comment: No link que tem lá tem links para outras coisas, é importante ler tudo, apesar de ser bastante coisa é muito importante. Hoje a captura de exceção é o recurso mais mal usado em linguagens. Como você verá lá capturar `Exception` tem seu lugar, só não é neste. Note que eu não disse que você não deve capturar qualquer exceção (também não estou dizendo que deva). Se é para capturar tenha certo que consegue fazer algo útil com ela e capture a exceção mais específica possível. Se foi o `<br\>` que deu certo a configuração estava marcada para aceitar HTML.

Comment: Muito obrigado @bigown...

Answer (score 1):

No C# use o `Environment.NewLine` mais ou menos assim:

```
String mensagem = String.format(customerRequest + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + "{0}", customerEmail);
```

Answer (score 1):

Utilize "Environment.NewLine" concatenado com o restante da mensagem!

Comment: Oi Tiago, é legal que queira contribuir com o site, mas no caso, além da resposta não estar elaborada, repete o que já foi dito nas 2 respostas dadas há mais de 2 anos. Mas você pode [edit] e tentar acrescentar algum detalhe relevante não observado nas outras, se achar que é o caso. Seria legal uma lidinha em [Tour] e [Help] a hora que tiver um tempinho.