# Erro de Index na listbox

Tags: vb.net

Minha aplicação tem o seguinte código de inicio:

```
BuscaDiretorioPastaOriginal("Diretorio") // isso seria uma função **recursiva** de diretorios
BuscaDiretorioPastaPath("Diretorio") // isso seria uma função **recursiva** de diretorios
```

Esta função lista em duas `listBox`, ate ai tudo blz, mas suje o erro nesta função

```
Private Sub AnalisarNovoArquivo()

 CTN.LSTNewAqui.Items.Add(CTN.LSTOG.SelectedItem.ToString)  
 CTN.LSTOG.Items.Remove(CTN.LSTOG.SelectedItem.ToString)

 CTN.LSTNewAqui.SelectedIndex = 0 
 ListaArray(0) = CTN.LSTNewAqui.SelectedItem.ToString  'Adiciona ao Index 0 na lista de array

end sub
```

Esta parte da função acusa que o valor não é valido para `selectedIndex`, o motivo seria pela parte de cima ai aonde tem `CTN.Items.Remove(CTN.LSTOG.SelectedItem.ToString)`.

**OBS:** a função funciona corretamente se usada um `Try`, mas como retorna esse erro?

Função que acusa o erro:

```
    Try
        For ItemsI = 0 To CTN.LSTOG.Items.Count - 1
            CTN.LSTOG.SelectedIndex = ItemsI
            CTN.LSTPath.SelectedIndex = ItemsI

            If CTN.LSTOG.SelectedItem.ToString <> CTN.LSTPath.SelectedItem.ToString Then
                Notificar("Existem novos arquivos a serem adicionados ao projeto.")
                AnalisarNovoArquivo()
                IniciarBuscaDeNovoArquivo()
                SplitCaminho()
                rem  VerificarDiretorios()
                CopiarNovoArquivo()
            End If
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception


    End Try
```

Comment: Qual o erro que apareceu?

Comment: Não funciona corretamente se usar um `Try`, você esconde o erro com ele. Jamais Use `Catch` sem fazer nada dentro dele. E só faça algo útil, algo que resolva o problema ou dê informações que ajudem resolver o problema. Caso contrário ele só prejudica. E quase sempre capturar uma `Exception` é outro erro porque são raros os casos que que dá para fazer algo útil com uma exceção tão genérica. Para aprender sobre exceções comece (mas não pare neste post, siga os *links*) lendo essa resposta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/30124/

Comment: Tipo eu entendo mas ou menos li muito o MSDN mas o deixei puro pelo simples fato de si eu colocar algo dentro a aplicação para, já se deixa pura a aplicação corre normalmente, sem da erro algum. O erro foi O Valor ex:31 não é valido para SelectedIndex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Private Sub AnalisarNovoArquivo()

  CTN.LSTNewAqui.Items.Add(CTN.LSTOG.SelectedItem.ToString)  
  CTN.LSTOG.Items.RemoveAt(CInt(CTN.LSTOG.SelectedIndex))

  CTN.LSTNewAqui.SelectedIndex = 0 
  ListaArray.Items.Insert(0, CTN.LSTOG.SelectedItem.ToString)

end sub
```