# Ler um arquivo TXT, ordenar, e salvar um novo arquivo Java

Tags: java, string, classificação, estrutura-de-dados, array

Estou fazendo um trabalho para a faculdade, e não estou conseguindo ler o arquivo e jogar os dados dentro de um ***ArrayList*** para ordenar os dados, abaixo segue como está o meu código até agora

```
public class Teste {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    ArrayList<String> vet = new ArrayList<>();
    String aux = null;
    int i = 0;
    vet.add("nome");
    vet.add("cidade");
    vet.add("estado");
    vet.add("aula");
    vet.add("cifra");


      BufferedReader lerArq = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Teste.txt"));
      String s;
      int n = 0;
      try{
          while ((s = lerArq.readLine()) != null){
              n++;
          }
          System.out.println(s);
      }
   catch(Exception e){
       System.out.println("Excecao1\n");
   }

    System.out.println("Vetor desordenado: ");
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        System.out.println(" " + vet.get(i));
    }
    System.out.println(" ");
    for (i = 0; i < vet.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < vet.size()-1; j++) {
            if (vet.get(j).compareToIgnoreCase(vet.get(j + 1)) > 0) {
                aux = vet.get(j);
                vet.set(j, vet.get(j + 1));
                vet.set(j + 1, aux);
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Vetor organizado:");
    for (i = 0; i < vet.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(" " + vet.get(i));

    }
    int x = 1;
     System.out.println(vet.get(x-1));
}
}
```

A ordenação está funcionando, só não estou conseguindo usar o ***FileReader***, alguma dica de como jogar os dados para dentro do ***ArrayList***?

Lembrando, os dados contidos no txt são os mesmos do abaixo, 5 palavras, cada uma em uma nova linha.

```
    vet.add("nome");
    vet.add("cidade");
    vet.add("estado");
    vet.add("aula");
    vet.add("cifra");
```

Comment: como as palavras estão no ficheiro? separadas por linhas ou na mesma linha? ou isso não é relevante?

Comment: Veja isto, é importante (talvez não para seu problema mas para sempre): http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/30168/101. A leitura está apresentando algum erro? Ou está imprimindo os dados lidos corretamente e você só não consegue por os dados lidos no `ArrayList`? Eu imagino que esses 5 `add`s foram colocados só para testar, certo?

Comment: ramaral, estão separadas por linha.

bigow, a leitura está dando certo, só não estou conseguindo inserir os dados lidos dentro do meu arraylist, para esse fazer a ordenação.

Comment: Tem um modo de fazer a ordenação sem o arraylist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se as palavras estiveram uma em cada linha, podes usar este codigo:

```
try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt"))) {
        String line = br.readLine();

        while (line != null) {
            vet.add(line);
            line = br.readLine();
        }
    }
```

Comment: o teu código funcionou, consegui fazer a leitura do arquivo, mostrar na tela desordenado, ordenar, e mostrar na tela ordenado. Obrigado!

Comment: se o seu problema foi resolvido pode marcar a resposta como certa...

Comment: acabei esquecendo... estava fazendo outros ajustes. marquei agora!