# Instrução throw está deixando o sistema inconsistente

Tags: c#, exceção, throw

tenho um try..catch e no catch o colega que fez deixo apenas throw.

```
catch(){throw;}
```

Bem, a intenção minha é tratar todas essa `exceptions` e não deixar apenas `throw`. Mas como eu cheguei agora aqui na empresa, já cheguei e ter que resolver problemas e codificar novas funcionalidades. Acontece, que descobri hoje que no ambiente de produção simplesmente deixar o `throw` como está, dá pau no sistema com diferentes comportamentos não esperados. Bem, a resposta é tratar o `throw`. O que eu gostaria de saber o que acontece com o `throw` de forma a dá esse tipo de erro em determinados ambiente e outros não. O ambiente de produção o nosso usuário acessa via portal, pois eles estão em vários locais(estados) do país. No ambiente de Desenv ou Homol, a url montada de acesso ao sistema é bem simples, tipo: `localhost:porta/Default.aspx`, em homol temos algo como: `brcohmlg:porta/Default.aspx`, agora em produção não. A `url` montada é bem complexa, bem maior que essa e não sei se isso tem algo a ver.

Comment: Eu venho falando disto há tempos aqui. Muita gente não entende que exceções são complicadas, não pode ficar usando elas sem dominar completamente o assunto. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/30168/101. Neste caso usar um `throw` sozinho não faz o menor sentido. E isto mostra que o programador não sabia o que estava fazendo. O problema provavelmente nem está nesta parte. Como você não conhece bem o sistema não será fácil achar todos os lugares onde causa problema. Se precisar de ajuda mais específica, vai ter que dar bem mais detalhes. E nem sei se caberia aqui tudo o que é necessário.

Answer (score 8):

A utilização da instrução `throw` sozinha dentro do bloco `catch()` faz com que a exceção capturada seja novamente lançada, tem o mesmo efeito de como não existisse o bloco `try/catch`

Se existe alguma inconsistência no comportamento do sistema, julgo que não tem a haver com o `throw` por si, mas sim com o tipo de erro que está a ser capturado/lançado.

Comment: Só para complementar... A instrução `throw` é válida porque você pode fazer mais coisas no `catch` além de relançar a mesma exceção. Por exemplo, se houve um erro e você está no catch, você pode fazer um *rollback* da operação do seu método e passar a exceção para o próximo contexto abaixo na pilha de execução. Muito útil. Mas `throw` sozinho dentro do catch é coisa ruim mesmo. Isso é mais feio que bater na própria mãe.

Comment: "Isso é mais feio que bater na própria mãe." ahahah @Renan

Comment: Entendi aqui porque o throw está sozinho. É quando a página vem do designer, todas vem assim com o throw para depois receber tratamento. O colega designer aqui envia tudo como throw pois ele não sabe o que fazer. Cabe a nós desenvolvedores tratar. Como o cara que estava aqui antes deixou muita coisa assim, eu venho pegando alguns problemas e desconfiava do throw, por isso o meu post.