# Sockets em java

Tags: java, socket

Implementar um programa em Java que aguarde conexões de rede direcionadas à porta 13131 e, dependendo de informações que lhe serão transmitidas através da acima mencionada conexão, realizar exclusões de filmes.

Tendo em vista que muitos programas poderão se conectar simultaneamente ao seu programa, solicitando uma exclusão, seu programa deverá fazer seu trabalho concorrentemente por seu programa.

As detecções e tratamentos de erros que, eventualmente, venham a ocorrer em seu programa deverão se utilizar do mecanismo de exceções.

Veja abaixo a especificação do protocolo a ser seguido por seu programa:

```
R: "Id"
ES: "SUC"
EI: "ERR"
```

- R: indica que o que vem entre aspas a seguir deve ser recebido por se programa;
- ES: significa que o que vem entre aspas a seguir deve ser enviado por seu programa em caso de sucesso;
- EI: significa que o que vem entre aspas a seguir deve ser enviado por seu programa em caso de insucesso.

Tenho esse exercício para fazer mas estou com dificuldades, vou postar meu código e o que quero fazer é enviar os dados, que não estou conseguindo.

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class ClienteSMTP
{
    private Socket         canalDeComunicacao = null;
    private BufferedReader entrada            = null;
    private PrintWriter    saida              = null;

    public ClienteSMTP (String servidor, int porta) throws Exception
    {
        try
        {
            canalDeComunicacao = new Socket(servidor, porta);
        }
        catch (UnknownHostException e)
        {
            throw new Exception ("desconhecido");
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            throw new Exception ("incomunicavel");
        }

        try
        {
            entrada = new BufferedReader (
                      new InputStreamReader (
                      canalDeComunicacao.
                      getInputStream ()));
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            throw new Exception ("error na entrada");
        }

        try
        {
            saida = new PrintWriter (
                    new OutputStreamWriter (
                    canalDeComunicacao.
                    getOutputStream()));
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            throw new Exception ("error na  saida");
        }
    }

    public void envieFilme (String resposta)
                               throws Exception
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Por que você captura uma exceção mais especializada apenas para lançar outra generalizada sem resolver problema algum? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/30168/101

Comment: Tudo bem,mas o meu maior problema é mandar a resposta para o "cliente", que é o tal do "id" "suc" "err",sabe como fazer isso?

Comment: @RodolfoOliveira, pelo que pude entender, o seu **cliente** irá enviar para o servidor o id de um filme e o servidor irá processar a exclusão e retornar `SUC` ou `ERR`, é isso mesmo? Se for isso, poderia disponibilizar também o código referente ao **servidor**?

Comment: Descupe mas, o que mais me parece é que você pega as especificações do cliente e posta como uma pergunta aqui no fórum, acho que isso foge dos princípios do site.

Comment: não existe uma duvida clara, um bom ponto de partida é esse: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/

Comment: Como a sua pergunta é bem genérica, vou lhe indicar esse material para estudo: [Apostila Sockets Caelum](https://www.caelum.com.br/apostila-java-orientacao-objetos/apendice-sockets/) Explica detalhadamente o funcionamento e apresenta exemplos

Answer (score 1):

Sua questão é muito generica, vejo que a dificuldade pode ser geral quanto ao desenvolvimento de **Sockets**.

Uma definição concisa de Socket é:

> Socket é um endpoint(terminal) de comunicação bidirecional entre dois
>   programas em uma rede. Um socket é vinculado a uma porta, assim a
>   camada TCP pode identificar a aplicação que o qual o dado será
>   destinado e consequentemente enviado.

Recomendo a leitura desse material da Oracle referente a Sockets no Java:

[Lesson: All About Sockets](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/)

**Exemplo de Socket Server:**

```
public class KnockKnockServer {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        if (args.length != 1) {
            System.err.println("Usage: java KnockKnockServer <port number>");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        int portNumber = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

        try ( 
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portNumber);
            Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
            PrintWriter out =
                new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        ) {

            String inputLine, outputLine;

            // Initiate conversation with client
            KnockKnockProtocol kkp = new KnockKnockProtocol();
            outputLine = kkp.processInput(null);
            out.println(outputLine);

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                outputLine = kkp.processInput(inputLine);
                out.println(outputLine);
                if (outputLine.equals("Bye."))
                    break;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Exception caught when trying to listen on port "
                + portNumber + " or listening for a connection");
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

**Exemplo de Socket Client:**

```
public class KnockKnockClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        if (args.length != 2) {
            System.err.println(
                "Usage: java EchoClient <host name> <port number>");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        String hostName = args[0];
        int portNumber = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);

        try (
            Socket kkSocket = new Socket(hostName, portNumber);
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(kkSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(kkSocket.getInputStream()));
        ) {
            BufferedReader stdIn =
                new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            String fromServer;
            String fromUser;

            while ((fromServer = in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println("Server: " + fromServer);
                if (fromServer.equals("Bye."))
                    break;

                fromUser = stdIn.readLine();
                if (fromUser != null) {
                    System.out.println("Client: " + fromUser);
                    out.println(fromUser);
                }
            }
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            System.err.println("Don't know about host " + hostName);
            System.exit(1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for the connection to " +
                hostName);
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cara, quando eu fui aprender a trabalhar com sockets tive um tutorial muito bom do qual dispensa comentários, basicamente você precisa de dois arquivos que estão abaixo, então é só rodar o C`hatServer.java` e depois o `ChatClient.java` passando o id do servidor e o seu nick, ele tem uma interface simples em swing apenas para facilitar a interação. Para entender basta dar uma olhada no código como é relativamente curto e ir debugando.

A fonte é: http://cs.lmu.edu/~ray/notes/javanetexamples/

ChatServer.java

```
package com.mageddo.sockets;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.HashSet;

/**
 * A multithreaded chat room server.  When a client connects the
 * server requests a screen name by sending the client the
 * text "SUBMITNAME", and keeps requesting a name until
 * a unique one is received.  After a client submits a unique
 * name, the server acknowledges with "NAMEACCEPTED".  Then
 * all messages from that client will be broadcast to all other
 * clients that have submitted a unique screen name.  The
 * broadcast messages are prefixed with "MESSAGE ".
 *
 * Because this is just a teaching example to illustrate a simple
 * chat server, there are a few features that have been left out.
 * Two are very useful and belong in production code:
 *
 *     1. The protocol should be enhanced so that the client can
 *        send clean disconnect messages to the server.
 *
 *     2. The server should do some logging.
 */
public class ChatServer {

    /**
     * The port that the server listens on.
     */
    private static final int PORT = 9001;

    /**
     * The set of all names of clients in the chat room.  Maintained
     * so that we can check that new clients are not registering name
     * already in use.
     */
    private static HashSet<String> names = new HashSet<String>();

    /**
     * The set of all the print writers for all the clients.  This
     * set is kept so we can easily broadcast messages.
     */
    private static HashSet<PrintWriter> writers = new HashSet<PrintWriter>();

    /**
     * The appplication main method, which just listens on a port and
     * spawns handler threads.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("The chat server is running.");
        ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(PORT);
        try {
            while (true) {
                new Handler(listener.accept()).start();
            }
        } finally {
            listener.close();
        }
    }

    /**
     * A handler thread class.  Handlers are spawned from the listening
     * loop and are responsible for a dealing with a single client
     * and broadcasting its messages.
     */
    private static class Handler extends Thread {
        private String name;
        private Socket socket;
        private BufferedReader in;
        private PrintWriter out;

        /**
         * Constructs a handler thread, squirreling away the socket.
         * All the interesting work is done in the run method.
         */
        public Handler(Socket socket) {
            this.socket = socket;
        }

        /**
         * Services this thread's client by repeatedly requesting a
         * screen name until a unique one has been submitted, then
         * acknowledges the name and registers the output stream for
         * the client in a global set, then repeatedly gets inputs and
         * broadcasts them.
         */
        public void run() {
            try {

                // Create character streams for the socket.
                in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    socket.getInputStream()));
                out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);

                // Request a name from this client.  Keep requesting until
                // a name is submitted that is not already used.  Note that
                // checking for the existence of a name and adding the name
                // must be done while locking the set of names.
                while (true) {
                    out.println("SUBMITNAME");
                    name = in.readLine();
                    if (name == null) {
                        return;
                    }
                    synchronized (names) {
                        if (!names.contains(name)) {
                            names.add(name);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }

                // Now that a successful name has been chosen, add the
                // socket's print writer to the set of all writers so
                // this client can receive broadcast messages.
                out.println("NAMEACCEPTED");
                writers.add(out);

                // Accept messages from this client and broadcast them.
                // Ignore other clients that cannot be broadcasted to.
                while (true) {
                    String input = in.readLine();
                    if (input == null) {
                        return;
                    }
                    for (PrintWriter writer : writers) {
                        writer.println("MESSAGE " + name + ": " + input);
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            } finally {
                // This client is going down!  Remove its name and its print
                // writer from the sets, and close its socket.
                if (name != null) {
                    names.remove(name);
                }
                if (out != null) {
                    writers.remove(out);
                }
                try {
                    socket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

e ChatClient.java

```
package com.mageddo.sockets;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

/**
 * A simple Swing-based client for the chat server.  Graphically
 * it is a frame with a text field for entering messages and a
 * textarea to see the whole dialog.
 *
 * The client follows the Chat Protocol which is as follows.
 * When the server sends "SUBMITNAME" the client replies with the
 * desired screen name.  The server will keep sending "SUBMITNAME"
 * requests as long as the client submits screen names that are
 * already in use.  When the server sends a line beginning
 * with "NAMEACCEPTED" the client is now allowed to start
 * sending the server arbitrary strings to be broadcast to all
 * chatters connected to the server.  When the server sends a
 * line beginning with "MESSAGE " then all characters following
 * this string should be displayed in its message area.
 */
public class ChatClient {

    BufferedReader in;
    PrintWriter out;
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Chatter");
    JTextField textField = new JTextField(40);
    JTextArea messageArea = new JTextArea(8, 40);

    /**
     * Constructs the client by laying out the GUI and registering a
     * listener with the textfield so that pressing Return in the
     * listener sends the textfield contents to the server.  Note
     * however that the textfield is initially NOT editable, and
     * only becomes editable AFTER the client receives the NAMEACCEPTED
     * message from the server.
     */
    public ChatClient() {

        // Layout GUI
        textField.setEditable(false);
        messageArea.setEditable(false);
        frame.getContentPane().add(textField, "North");
        frame.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(messageArea), "Center");
        frame.pack();

        // Add Listeners
        textField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            /**
             * Responds to pressing the enter key in the textfield by sending
             * the contents of the text field to the server.    Then clear
             * the text area in preparation for the next message.
             */
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                out.println(textField.getText());
                textField.setText("");
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Prompt for and return the address of the server.
     */
    private String getServerAddress() {
        return JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
            frame,
            "Enter IP Address of the Server:",
            "Welcome to the Chatter",
            JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
    }

    /**
     * Prompt for and return the desired screen name.
     */
    private String getName() {
        return JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
            frame,
            "Choose a screen name:",
            "Screen name selection",
            JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    }

    /**
     * Connects to the server then enters the processing loop.
     */
    private void run() throws IOException {

        // Make connection and initialize streams
        String serverAddress = getServerAddress();
        Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddress, 9001);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            socket.getInputStream()));
        out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);

        // Process all messages from server, according to the protocol.
        while (true) {
            String line = in.readLine();
            if (line.startsWith("SUBMITNAME")) {
                out.println(getName());
            } else if (line.startsWith("NAMEACCEPTED")) {
                textField.setEditable(true);
            } else if (line.startsWith("MESSAGE")) {
                messageArea.append(line.substring(8) + "\n");
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Runs the client as an application with a closeable frame.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ChatClient client = new ChatClient();
        client.frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        client.frame.setVisible(true);
        client.run();
    }
}
```