# Erro: Não foi possível carregar arquivo ou assembly

Tags: c#

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação desktop com c#, e está dando o seguinte erro quando faço alguma interação com o Banco.

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in BackupRN.dll

Additional information: Não foi possível carregar arquivo ou assembly 'Mono.Security, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0738eb9f132ed756' ou uma de suas dependências. O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado.
```

Mais detalhado.

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147024894
  Message=Não foi possível carregar arquivo ou assembly 'Mono.Security, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0738eb9f132ed756' ou uma de suas dependências. O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado.
  Source=BackupRN
  FileName=Mono.Security, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0738eb9f132ed756
  FusionLog==== Informações sobre estado pré-associação ===
LOG: DisplayName = Mono.Security, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0738eb9f132ed756
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Users/Glauco/OneDrive/Projects/ProjetoBackup/ProjetoBackup/bin/Debug/
LOG: PrivatePath inicial = NULL
Chamando assembly: Npgsql, Version=2.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5d8b90d52f46fda7.
===
LOG: esta associação começa no contexto de carregamento default.
LOG: usando arquivo de configuração de aplicativo: C:\Users\Glauco\OneDrive\Projects\ProjetoBackup\ProjetoBackup\bin\Debug\SafeBackupConfig.exe.config
LOG: usando arquivo de configuração de host: 
LOG: usando arquivo de configuração da máquina de C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: referência pós-política: Mono.Security, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0738eb9f132ed756
LOG: a mesma associação foi vista antes e falhou com hr = 0x80070002.

  StackTrace:
       em BackupRN.ArquivoRN.buscar(Int32 idServidor) na c:\Users\Glauco\OneDrive\Projects\ProjetoBackup\BackupRN\ArquivoRN.cs:linha 40
       em Backup.frmPrincipal.btnTestar_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) na c:\Users\Glauco\OneDrive\Projects\ProjetoBackup\ProjetoBackup\Principal.cs:linha 41
       em System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       em System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       em System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
       em System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
       em System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       em System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
       em System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
       em System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       em System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       em System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       em System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
       em System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
       em System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       em System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       em System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
       em Backup.Program.Main() na c:\Users\Glauco\OneDrive\Projects\ProjetoBackup\ProjetoBackup\Program.cs:linha 19
       em System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       em System.AppDomain.nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       em System.Runtime.Hosting.ManifestRunner.Run(Boolean checkAptModel)
       em System.Runtime.Hosting.ManifestRunner.ExecuteAsAssembly()
       em System.Runtime.Hosting.ApplicationActivator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext activationContext, String[] activationCustomData)
       em System.Runtime.Hosting.ApplicationActivator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext activationContext)
       em System.Activator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext activationContext)
       em Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssemblyDebugInZone()
       em System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       em System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       em System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       em System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       em System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

Metodos
Ele da erro no throw da RN

```
public Arquivo buscar(int idServidor)
    {
    Arquivo banco = new Arquivo();
    try
        {
        //Valida informações a serem gravadas

        dao = new ArquivoDAO();

        banco = dao.buscar(idServidor);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        throw e;
        }
    return banco;
}
```

Metodo na DAO

```
public Arquivo buscar(int idServidor)
{
    try
    {
        DAOFactory dao = new DAOFactory();
        conexao = dao.CriaConexao();

        //String sql = "select max(id) from arquivo";
        //NpgsqlCommand sqlCon = new NpgsqlCommand(@sql, conexao);
        conexao.Open();

        //NpgsqlDataReader drCon;

        //drCon = sqlCon.ExecuteReader();

        //while (drCon.Read())
        //{
        Arquivo arquivo = new Arquivo();
        //arquivo.Id = Convert.ToInt32(drCon[0]);
        string sql2 = "select * from arquivo where idservidor = " + idServidor;
        NpgsqlCommand sqlCon2 = new NpgsqlCommand(@sql2, conexao);


        //drCon.Close();
        //conexao.Open();
        NpgsqlDataReader drCon2;
        drCon2 = sqlCon2.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

        while (drCon2.Read())
            {
            Arquivo arquivo2 = new Arquivo(Convert.ToInt32(drCon2[0]), drCon2[1].ToString(), Convert.ToInt32(drCon2[2]));
            drCon2.Close();
            return arquivo2;
            }
            //}

        Arquivo arquivo1 = new Arquivo(0, "", 0);
        return arquivo1;
    }
    catch (Exception erro)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("erro " + erro.Message);
        throw erro;
    }
}
```

Comment: Você tem o `Mono.Security.dll` junto à aplicação? Poste o código do método que está dando erro.

Comment: Coloquei os metodos.

Comment: Você está complicando o tratamento de erro. Seu código tem um problema muito comum que não pode mais acontecer. Veja: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/30168/101 Siga os links dessa resposta e vai lendo tudo. Tem bastante coisa pra ler mas é de extrema importância você entender como exceções devem ser usadas. É o oposto do que você está fazendo. Nunca capture uma exceção sem fazer nada útil. Nunca lance a exceção novamente desta forma. "Nunca" capture `Exception` (leia os textos para saber quando pode). Fica mais difícil identificar o problema desta forma.

Comment: Eu vou ler isso quando chegar em casa, só por esse erro ai não tem como você me ajudar? Estou precisando disso urgente, não terei tempo para ler agora. Eu debuguei o projeto e ele esta parando quando tenta estabelecer a conexão com o banco.

Comment: Você está escondendo o erro real. Então fica difícil dizer o que está acontecendo. Mas dá uma olhada no arquivo que eu falei. Se a mensagem estiver correta pode ser algo relacionado com ele.

Comment: Ok, obrigado, vou ver aqui.

Comment: Também aparece esse erro. Tem algo a ver. Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto.