# Como tratar um Fatal Error

Tags: php, recuperação-de-erros

Como pegar um *fatal error* para que ele não encerre a aplicação? Isso deve ser limitado somente a uma parte do código (isso não trará riscos a aplicação)?

Exemplo: gostaria que todas as mensagens de *fatal error* geradas dentro deste bloco não encerrem a aplicação:

```
if($DocInfo->http_status_code === 200){
    //Print Page Title
    $html = str_get_html($DocInfo->content);
    $title = $html->find('title');
    echo $title[0]->plaintext.'<br />';
}
```

Comment: Desculpe displicência minha, Não encerrem a aplicação

Comment: Qual é o fatal error que você recebe? As vezes é melhor  evitar o erro do que tentar se recuperar dele.

Comment: @AndréRibeiro, não há como evitar o fatal error, ele é gerado quando $DocInfo->content é falso, (fica falso por causa de erro de rede entre outros motivos peculiares) burlarmos o fatal error nesta parte do código não influenciaria o funcionamento correto da aplicação

Comment: @RicardoHenrique e o problema é que ele fica falso, é só verificar antes e não usá-lo. Não vou dizer que não existe nada que pode ser evitado, claro que tem, mas não parece ser este caso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quando você quer evitar que erros aconteçam tem que se perguntar algumas coisas:

- Que tipo de problema você espera que aconteça? É possível fazer uma verificação antes que ele aconteça? Se puder, faça.
- É possível verificar se ocorreu o erro depois sem maiores problemas? Verifique antes que o resultado seja usado e gere outro erro.
- Se nada disto é possível, quais as exceções que você sabe que podem acontecer neste trecho? Capture estas exceções específicas.
- Não sabe o que capturar? Capture todas. Isto não deveria ser feito mas é a última alternativa.

Como evitar o erro (baseado no que foi dito no comentário da pergunta):

```
if ($DocInfo->http_status_code === 200) {
    if ($DocInfo->content) {
        $html = str_get_html($DocInfo->content);
        $title = $html->find('title');
        echo $title[0]->plaintext.'<br />';
    } else {
        echo "deu erro aqui";
        //faz alguma coisa útil
    }
}
```

Eu colocaria exemplos de captura de exceções mais específicas se eu tivesse acesso à documentação da classe sendo usada (e a documentação seja bem feita, o que costuma ser raro).

O último caso seria:

```
try { 
    if ($DocInfo->http_status_code === 200) {
        //Print Page Title
        $html = str_get_html($DocInfo->content);
        $title = $html->find('title');
        echo $title[0]->plaintext.'<br />';
    }
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    echo "deu erro aqui";
    //faz alguma coisa útil
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Syntax/Validation.php).

[Veja mais sobre capturar `Exception`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/30124/101).

Além disto é possível regrar uma função para capturar todos os erros. Também não é recomendado na maior parte dos casos.

```
register_shutdown_function("nomeDaFuncao");
```

Aí você escreve o que quiser na função `nomeDaFuncao`.

Mas há motivos para se evitar essas formas não recomendadas. Não vá no caminho que parece mais fácil porque ele se tornará um complicador.

Se tem um erro fatal é porque tem um erro de programação. Então ele deve ser corrigido. Não é para fazer de conta que o erro não existe. Pode parecer que não é erro de programação mas é se você pode evitá-lo. E parece que ele pode ser evitado.

Comment: o catch irá capturar o Fatal Error?

Comment: `try/catch` não irá capturar o fatal error.

Comment: @RicardoHenrique você está se concentrando na parte errada da resposta.

Comment: @AndréRibeiro Até onde eu sei um erro fatal só ocorre se uma exceção não for capturada ou se a própria exceção geram um erro. Tem algum lugar que indique o contrário? Gostaria de saber, já que o PHP tem essas coisas estranhas. Até onde eu sei o erro fatal ocorre em consequência da não captura da exceção.

Comment: @bigown [Veja este teste](https://ideone.com/Ty69PQ)

Comment: @AndréRibeiro É, mas tem algum lugar que documente isto? Não sigo resultados, gosto de estudar o funcionamento oficial. Pode até existir um motivo para isto acontecer e explicação porque ocorre. De qualquer forma, eu não acho ruim, é erro de programação, e erros de programação não deveria ser capturados mesmo.

Comment: @bigown Nesse caso o `try/catch` não funciona porque não é gerada nenhuma exceção, mas um `E_ERROR` (que é fatal e interrompe o script). Infelizmente na documentação do PHP isso não está descrito explicitamente.

Comment: @bigown Até a versão 5, o PHP não tinha tratamento de exceções, era tudo na base de *errors* e *warnings*. Todo o código legado ainda se baseia nisso. E os erros nunca serão capturados por um `catch`, a menos que você tenha [instruído o PHP a fazer isso](http://php.net/manual/en/class.errorexception.php#errorexception.example.error-handler). Quando você diz que uma exceção não capturada gera um erro fatal, estaria se referindo ao algum erro em tempo de execução no código-fonte do PHP, em C++? Porque em PHP mesmo isso não acontece, ao menos não por *default*.

Comment: Está certo, tinha me esquecido completamente disto. Mas ainda assim a solução para o problema do AP é outra :)