# Passar parâmetro Type para método genérico em runtime

Tags: c#, reflexão, genéricos

Tenho um método que utilizo para deserializar dados:

```
public static class CustomJson<T> where T: class, new()
{
    public static T Deserialize(string data)
    {
        try
        {
            return string.IsNullOrEmpty(data) 
                      ? default(T) 
                      : Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(data);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exceptions.SerializationException(SerializationType.Json, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

O tipo a ser utilizado na deserialização eu conheço somente em runtime:

```
public void TesteCustomJson(string package, string methodName)
{
    try
    {
        var serviceFactory = new ServiceFactory();
        var service = serviceFactory.GetService<ITesteService>();

        var method = service.GetType().GetMethod(methodName);
        if (method != null)
        {
            var parameter = method.GetParameters().FirstOrDefault();
            if (parameter != null)
            {
                var parameterType = parameter.ParameterType;
                var result = Framework.Utils.Serialization.CustomJson<parameterType>.Deserialize(package);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(ex);
    }
}
```

Fazendo dessa maneira não compila, é gerado o seguinte erro:

> The type or namespace name 'parameterType' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Existe alguma forma de passar o tipo a ser deserializado conhecendo-o somente em tempo de execução?

Comment: Por que você só conhece em *runtime*? Tem certeza disto? Pelo trecho postado isto não fica claro. Além disto. Você quer realmente que um erro de memória ou outro erro seja reportado como um erro de serialização? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/30168/101

Comment: Na verdade eu conheço os tipos, porém como posso tratá-los de uma forma genérica sendo que são centenas de tipos diferentes? Penso que se pegar o tipo em runtime poderia ser menos trabalhoso. Quanto ao tratamento de erro, iremos melhorá-lo, aqui foi só um exemplo.

Comment: Se você sabe o tipo em tempo de compilação, deve tratar disto em tempo de compilação. O caminho estava correto. Talvez o problema esteja no uso mas você não postou informações relevantes de como está usando. Como não vi todo o código não pode afirmar mas acho que você sabe qual é o tipo de `parameter`, então use este tipo e seja feliz.

Comment: Postei o método de teste completo.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/232621/4322614

Comment: Obrigado @Mateus, corresponde com a resposta do Omni.

Comment: Sim @PauloBalbino, eu encontrei essa solução no SO, porém quando fui ver já tinham respondido, para não perder a viagem postei o que encontrei.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pode utilizar o seguinte código para passar um tipo genérico durante o *runtime*:

```
public static class CustomJson<T> where T : class, new()
{
    public static T Deserialize(string data)
    {
        try
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(data)) 
                return new T();
            return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(data);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            throw;
        }
    }
}

public class TestClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public TestClass()
    {
    }
}

public void TestGeneric()
{
    Type custom = typeof(CustomJson<>);
    Type newInstance = custom .MakeGenericType(typeof(TestClass));
    MethodInfo mi = newInstance.GetMethod("Deserialize");
    var res = mi.Invoke(null, new object[] { "{Id: 3}" });
}
```

Tenha em atenção o método [`.MakeGenericType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.type.makegenerictype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Sumariamente, o método cria um novo `CustomJson<T>` com os tipos providenciados no método. Embora aqui se substituía apenas `T`, o mesmo poderia ser aplicado a mais tipos genéricos.

Exemplo no [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/R25WAD).

Comment: Obrigado, vou fazer os testes.