# Formatação de Strings para RG

Tags: c#, .net, string

Como posso formatar essa *String*: 12345678x para essa: 12.345.678-X ?
Tentei usar o `String.Format` mas não consegui.

Resolvido:

```
public string RgFormat(object rg)
{   
    string strRg = rg.ToString();
    return strRg.Substring(0, 2) + "." + strRg.Substring(2, 3) + "." + strRg.Substring(5, 3) + "-" + strRg.Substring(8, 1).ToUpper();             
}

public string CpfFormat(object cpf)
{         
    string strCpf = cpf.ToString();
    return strCpf.Substring(0, 3) + "." + strCpf.Substring(3, 3) + "." +      strCpf.Substring(6, 3) + "-" + strCpf.Substring(9, 2).ToUpper();    
}
```

Comment: `String.Format` é adequado apenas para números. Aquele `X` é um número ou é o literal `X`?

Comment: Bom estamos falando de rg, alguns possui o digito caracter literal, nesse caso o X.

Comment: Resolvido +/- :) Olha isto: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/30168/101 Não capture `Exception` principalmente só para relançá-la. Tira esses `try catch` que eles estão ajudando zero e dificultando a depuração se der alguma exceção. E realmente existe motivo para o dado vir como `object`? Não tem outro jeito de resolver isto?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez o `String.Format` é adequado apenas para números? Qual o problema de usar com strings, por exemplo?

Comment: Os dados que vem dos paramentros vem da grid através desse TemplateField por isso eu uso object.  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Cpf">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblCpf" runat="server" Text='<%# this.CpfFormat(DataBinder.Eval(Container,"DataItem.Cpf"))%>' />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>

Comment: @RichardDias O problema é aplicar uma formatação de máscara. Até hoje, só consegui fazer funcionar pra variáveis numéricas (`int`, `float`, `long`, `double`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Não consigo ver uma solução melhor que esta. Pensei em usar `ToString()` ou `string.Format()` mas não achei uma solução fácil (pode ser que tenha:

```
using static System.Console;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        WriteLine(FormataRG("12345678x"));
        WriteLine(FormataRG("123456789"));
    }
    public static string FormataRG(string texto) => texto.Substring(0, 2) + "." + texto.Substring(2, 3) + "." + texto.Substring(5, 3) + "-" + texto.Substring(8, 1).ToUpper();
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/QoeesL). E no [**.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pdCFGl). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/MaskRg.cs).

Note que se é RG mesmo, cada um pode ter um formato diferente então esta não é uma solução universal. Tem que identificar o formato antes. Validação já seria outra operação.

Comment: Bom o resultado é o que eu preciso, eu pensei que tivesse algum jeito de fazer com ToString ou String.Format(), o Cpf e Telefone eu fiz com ToString().

Comment: Mas obrigado vou usar o seu código.

Comment: Pode ser que exista mas por tudo o que eu sei e pensei, não achei algo que desse. O que até me estranhou. Se procurar bem pode ter uma forma mas se ficar menos legante que isto, não adianta nada.

Answer (score 2):

Uma alternativa à resposta do @Maniero é utilizar `Insert`.

```
using System;

public class Program
 {
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(mask("12345678x"));
    }

    public static string mask(string numbers) {
        return numbers.Insert(2, ".").Insert(6, ".").Insert(10, "-");
    }
 }
```

[Veja funcionando em @NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/J9qGmm).

Answer (score 0):

Tenta assim

```
Text1.Text = Text1.Text.Replace("X", "")

double numero;
if (Double.TryParse(Text1.Text, out numero))
      Text1.Text = numero.ToString(@"000\.000\.000\-X");
else
      MessageBox.Show("Valor inválido: " + Text1.Text);
```

Comment: Eu testei seu código mais tenho problema quando recebo um rg somente com números exemplo: 12.123.123-1, Ele coloca o X no final, talvez eu não tenha deixado claro na pergunta o que realmente precisava, de qualquer forma obrigado.

Comment: Mas não é pra formatar com X no final ?

Comment: Sim mas as vezes vem rg sem o X com digito numérico.