# Como tratar erro de chave duplicada?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sql-server, entity-framework, exceção

Como faço pra tratar erro de chave duplicada? Preciso exibir mensagem para o usuário que o "Item já está cadastrado"

Algo assim:

```
try{

  //tenta inserir no Banco de Dados
  context.Produto.Add(_produto);
  context.SaveChanges();

}catch(exceção 1){

  //tratar erro de chave duplicada

}catch(exceção 2){

  // tratar erro diferente de chave duplicada

}
```

O erro sempre retorna na classe `catch(Exception ex)`

```
        _repositorio.ProdutoEstoque.Add(_produtoEstoque);
        _repositorio.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (UpdateException ex)
    {
        SqlException innerException = ex.InnerException as SqlException;
        if (innerException != null && innerException.Number == 2627){                    
            //tratar erro de chave duplicada
            //o jeito que vai informar a view depende do resto da sua aplicação
            string msg = string.Empty;
            msg ="ERRO";
        }else
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
    catch (SqlException ex){
        if (ex.Number == 2627){
            string msg = string.Empty;
            msg = "ERRO";
        }else
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex){  
         throw;               
    }
}
```

#### Print erro

[image: Erro apresentado]

Comment: Que tal fazer uma consulta antes? Se estiver a gravar registos em várias tabelas em simultâneo, pode não saber onde existe a tal duplicação.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Acho que é isto que precisa.

```
try {
    context.Produto.Add(_produto);
    context.SaveChanges();
} catch (UpdateException ex) {
    SqlException innerException = ex.InnerException as SqlException;
    if (innerException != null && innerException.Number == 2627) {
        //tratar erro de chave duplicada
        //o jeito que vai informar a view depende do resto da sua aplicação
    } else {
        throw;
    }
} catch(exceção 2) {
    // tratar erro diferente de chave duplicada
}
```

Pela edição da pergunta ainda tem mais um nível de exceção `DBUpdateException`. Aí tem que capturar ela primeiro.

Se estiver usando C# 6 pode melhorar:

```
try {
    context.Produto.Add(_produto);
    context.SaveChanges();
} catch (UpdateException ex) when (innerException?.Number == 2627) {
    //tratar erro de chave duplicada
} catch(exceção 2) {
    // tratar erro diferente de chave duplicada
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Exception/Filter.cs).

Se a segunda exceção for `Exception` provavelmente é [melhor não capturar ali](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/30168/101).

Comment: Entendi... esse .Number == 2627 seria o código de erro para Chave Duplicada, vou testar e depois assinalo a resposta. Obrigado!

Comment: Isto. Vê aí se resolve o que quer.

Comment: bigown não deu certo, eu testei e percebi que sempre cai no Exception e não no UpdateException, eu coloquei um print do erro na pergunta e o trecho do código mais relevante.

Comment: Isto não dá para ver tudo. Me fala se tem mais alguma `InnerException` dentro da que aparece na imagem. Já vi que tinha que capturar a `DBUpdateException` antes da `UpdateException` mas deve ter mais.

Comment: Isso mesmo tem mais uma `InnerException`  a `DbUpdateException` eu a capturei e só tive que acrescentar:  `SqlException innerException = ex.InnerException.InnerException as SqlException;`