# Tratar Exception pelo código

Tags: c#, .net, exceção

No Visual Basic 6 existia o comando `err.number` onde é demonstrado o código do erro ocorrido.

Tenho uma aplicação em C# que tratamos a *exception* pela descrição da mensagem pois não localizei o comando que retorne o código do erro. Estou com um problema pois uma das maquinas foi trocado o sistema operacional a a mensagem da *exception* esta retornando em inglês e o tratamento que tenho é em português.

Existe algum comando que retorne o código do erro?

Verifiquei que existe um que exibe o tipo do erro, mas pelo que entendi pode ser um conjunto de erros relacionado ao tipo.

Comment: A que tipo de erro se refere? Quem o gera? Nem sempre um erro tem um número/código associado.

Comment: (...) que o distinga inequivocamente.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Acredito que deseja a propriedade [`HResult`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.exception.hresult?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_Exception_HResult), ela é a única forma de código disponível em todas as exceções. Mas sinceramente se precisa desta informação, muito provavelmente está fazendo algo errado, as próprias exceções são suficientes para classificar o erro.

Há casos que o código pode ser relevante, talvez o maior exemplo seja [`SQLException`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0), que tem a propriedade `ErrorCode` que exatamente pega o `HRESULT` de forma mais semântica. [Um exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/90212/101).

O funcionamento da exceção em C# é diferente do controle de erros do VB, aprenda usar da forma idiomática. Alias sugiro estudar profundamente o tratamento de exceções que é muito frequentemente usada de forma equivocada.

Answer (score 4):

Você pode usar o comando:

```
int code = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetExceptionCode();
```

Ele retornará o código da Exception que você busca