# Criar exceções personalizadas mais específicas ou mais genéricas?

Tags: java, exceção

Levando em conta que em um projeto é utilizada a prática de se criar exceções personalizadas, o que faz mais sentido?

Digo, criar uma exceção para cada possível erro previsto no código, especificando o nome da classe da exceção com o erro exato, ou senão tentar generalizar em "grupos" de erros?

#### Exemplo de classe personalizada bem especifica:

```java
   public class DataDeNascimentoDoUsuarioInvalidaException extends Exception {

   }
```

#### Exemplo de uma classe de exceção menos especifica:

```java
   public class CadastroDeUsuarioException extends Exception {

   }
```

#### Exemplo de uma classe de exceção personalizada mais generalizada:

```java
   public class CadastroException extends Exception{

   }
```

Existe algum critério para essa questão (por exemplo de algum autor, ou termo)?

Tenho a noção de que se criar exceções muito específicas, um projeto grande terá uma quantidade enorme de classes, mas sei que tem desenvolvedores que utilizam essa pratica, que na minha visão leiga é uma má prática.

Li o post bem parecido com esse que fala sobre tratamento de erro especifico x generalizado ([post](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/21939/37189)), mas esse post não aborda exceções personalizadas.

Comment: Sei que o site prefere perguntas menos subjetivas, mas gostaria de um norte para ter minha própria opnião a respeito dessa questão.

Comment: Talvez a pergunta que te ajude seja "preciso realmente de um exception específico para identificar uma situação"? por exemplo, uma classe de `CadastroUsuairo`, que insere em um banco uma entidade do tipo `CadastroUsuario` somente não precisaria de um exception exclusivo.

Comment: Lançar excepções não é a melhor abordagem para lidar com essas situações(validação do input do usuário).

Comment: Infelizmente, é uma pergunta baseada em opinião e o SO não aceita bem perguntas deste tipo. Mas para te dar um norte (mesmo que não te ajude especificamente no seu problema), eu prefiro criar o mínimo de exceções possível e controlo quase tudo por códigos de erro. Para ter uma ideia do que quero dizer, olha este repositório com a implementação: https://github.com/dherik/java-exception-handling . Lá tem um link para um artigo com mais detalhes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Não existe resposta definitiva para isso. Eu sei que as pessoas sempre querem uma regra mágica universal, mas só o problema, o contexto, o ambiente que está sendo desenvolvido pode determinar o que é mais adequado.

## Hierarquia

Isso não significa que toda exceção deva ser derivada de `Exception`, talvez o maior erro esteja aí. Você pode criar uma hierarquia de tipos, entre ter um modelo de exceções bem específicas e um modelo de ter exceções agrupadas, fique com os dois, pode ter níveis.

Pra modelar certo precisa entender de taxonomia e ontologia (alguns falam em dialética também), mesmo sem estudo formal, é o segredo.

Não é má prática criar um monte de exceção se é o modelo escolhido. Existe sempre o modelo em que a exceção não é usada para validação, para controle de fluxo. Eu já falei diversas vezes sobre isso, mas muita gente prefere a exceção para tudo. Se a pessoa escolhe isso tem que pagar o preço, e aí o correto é criar um monte de classes. Um dos motivos para não adotar exceção é justamente não ter que criar muitas classes, embora não seja o maior motivo.

Se vai usar exceção, use certo, e seja específico. A crítica que se faz a outros modelos é justamente não poder especificar o erro, o que não é verdade na maioria dos casos, então se você opta pela exceção e não usa a sua vantagem teórica, pra que está fazendo isso? Isso é importante porque boa parte dos programadores usa a exceção de forma errada e ganha o pior dos dois mundos. E pra mim é demonstração clara que ela nem quer usar exceção, mas usa porque aprendeu assim, faz o que todo mundo está fazendo sem questionar porque.

Em um domínio muito bem modelado, em que exceções são o meio de comunicação de invalidade de dados é necessário um monte de classes mesmo. Por isso algumas pessoas preferem uma modelagem mais pragmática em vez de fazer tudo perfeito. Falei disso em [Por que certos domínios são mais fáceis de modelar que outros?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/435459/101).

## Importância de criar classes específicas

O *post* citado não aborda exceções personalizadas explicitamente, mas implicitamente vale tudo o que está lá. De fato, tem muitas perguntas sobre exceção no site, mas poucas de como criar exceções personalizadas, sabe por quê? Porque quase ninguém as cria. Dá trabalho e as pessoas não querem ter trabalho. Então deveria usar o mecanismo que não dá trabalho e evitar um que dá e fazer uso errado dele para economizar.

Um dos motivos das pessoas capturarem exceções erradas (genéricas) é que elas não sabem ou não querem criar exceções personalizadas, e isso é um erro. Um erro contamina o outro.

## Domínio

Se for para fazer de qualquer jeito, isso não importa muito. Se quer fazer certo tem que perguntar para o domínio o que ele precisa. Quase sempre ele precisa de uma exceção só para ele.

Tudo tem a ver com o nível de abstração que está lidando. Isso é uma das coisas mais difíceis de definir. Por isso eu sempre falo que a maioria dos desenvolvedores modela errado, inclusive eu, porque é muito difícil e alguns paradigmas são mais difíceis porque te obriga modelar certo desde o começo (OOP, cof cof, pra arrumar o erro muda tanto que vira outro objeto).

Depende do quanto você terá que ser específico no tratamento daquilo. Faz sentido você criar uma exceção se não vai capturá-la genericamente? Para a maioria das pessoas não precisava ter exceções diversas, só precisava ter a `Exception`, elas não querem saber do resto. É um completo erro, mas para a prática delas é o correto.

Para quem é engenheiro de verdade costuma dizer que `Exception` deveria ser uma classe abstrata, que não resolve o problema da captura errada, mas resolve da pessoa ser genérica demais quando lança uma exceção. E como a maioria não teve a preocupação que o AP teve, vai reclamar e falar que a linguagem errou em não deixar instanciar essa classe.

Em domínios de negócios se você opta pela exceção é quase certo que cada classe terá uma exceção própria junto, ou algumas. A não ser de casos que as classes tenham relacionamento forte.

## Meio termo

Um outro detalhe importante é que algumas exceções podem conter códigos mais específicos em vez de criar hierarquia. Já falei disso em [É melhor ter um tipo de exceção para cada caso ou uma exceção mais geral?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/164502/101) e [Tratar Exception pelo código](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/290241/101) e exemplo real em [Como tratar erro de chave duplicada?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/90207/101)

Eu dou uma ideia sobre escolha disso em [Boas práticas com tratamento de exceção Java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/186617/101).

Eu acho que deve ser leitura obrigatória, mesmo que discorde: [Por que devemos evitar retornar códigos de erro?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21767/101).

Ou usa outro mecanismo ou usa a exceção do jeito certo. Exceção foi criada para ser específico, não ser é desvirtuamento do mecanismo. O quanto é o certo é onde entra a "arte" usada na engenharia.

Vira e mexe vejo umas atrocidades por aí. Funciona, mas não é o certo, uma hora você paga um preço. Cuidado para não abusar disto.

Muitas vezes o problema é até outro, mas não vou entrar nessa seara porque envolve toda a forma como fazemos software "moderno".

## Conclusão

Mas se não compreender bem tudo, pode tomar a decisão errada.

Leia tudo o que puder sobre exceção e um pouco mais. E aí comece tomar suas decisões. Só a experiência qualificada (a quantificada não ajuda muito, fazer errado por 20 anos só atrapalha) fará você tomar melhores decisões em cada caso.

Algumas pessoas preferem simplificar e escolhe um jeito e faz assim em tudo. Gasta menos tempo pra decidir, e ela lidará com as consequências dessa decisão.

A sua escolha será sua opinião, mas a base do conhecimento pode ser obtida de forma objetiva ou pelo menos com uma subjetividade fundamentada, até que você terá uma opinião sólida.

[Mais uma resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/30168/101) que pode ajudar.

[Uma resposta que eu dei](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/13611/101) que dá uma ideia boa sobre isso mas que alguns não gostam, mesmo ela estar de acordo com um dos caras que mais entende a computação e tem resultados extraordinários para mostrar. Eu não criei aquele conceito, eu reproduzi.

E ainda: [É uma boa prática lançar exceção nesses casos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15261/101).

É colateral, mas vale para ajudar decidir (em toda linguagem é assim, C++ tem tentado criar um mecanismo melhor): [Exceções consomem muito processamento. Verdade ou lenda?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5888/101). Imagine ler dados externos e validar um a um. O que levaria segundos pode levar horas, é sério, depois a pessoa não entende porque o sistema é lento.

Pesquise no site que tem outras interessantes. E tem gente que pensa diferente.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).