# Calcular raiz quadrada em C#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, matemática

Tenho uma calculadora feita em WPF C# com as operações básicas +,-,*,/, % . 
E agora queria tentar melhorar a minha calculadora.

```
namespace calculadora
 {
 public delegate float? dlgoperacao(float? a, float? b);

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex regex = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"[+-/*]", System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.None);
    const int PESO = 10;
    int? divisor = null;
    bool flag = false;

    float? op1 = 0, op2 = null;
    float? rslt = null;
    dlgoperacao operacao = null;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"imgs/2.jpg",UriKind.Relative));
    }//Fim Construtor

    protected float? calculaop(float? operori, ref  int? div, char ch)
    {
        float? rslt = null;
        if (ch == ',') { rslt = operori; div = 1; return rslt; }
        else
        {
            int digito = Convert.ToInt32(ch - 48);
            if (div == null) rslt = (operori == null) ? digito : (operori * PESO) + digito;
            else
            {
                div = div * 10;
                rslt = ((operori * div) + digito) / div;

            }
            return rslt;
        }

    }




    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button bt = (Button)sender;
        char[] ch = bt.Content.ToString().ToCharArray();
        if (char.IsDigit(ch[0].ToString(), 0) || ch[0] == ',')
        {
            if (flag)
            {
                op2 = calculaop(op2, ref divisor, ch[0]);
                // int i = regex.Match(txt.Text).Index;
                //txt.Text = txt.Text.Substring(0, i +1) +  " " + op2.ToString();
                txt.Text = op2.ToString();
            }
            else
            {

                op1 = calculaop(op1, ref divisor, ch[0]);
                txt.Text = op1.ToString();
            }

        }//if ch[0] is digit
        else
        {
            divisor = null;
            switch (ch[0])
            {
                case 'c':
                    flag = false;
                    op1 = op2 = null;
                    operacao = null;
                    txt.Text = "";
                    break;
                case '+':
                    if (op2 == null) flag = !flag;
                    else if (operacao != null)
                    {
                        op1 = operacao(op1, op2);
                        op2 = null;
                        flag = true;

                    }
                    operacao = (a, b) => a + b;
                    txt.Text = op1.ToString() + " + ";
                    break;
                case '-':
                    if (op2 == null) flag = !flag;
                    else if (operacao != null)
                    {
                        op1 = operacao(op1, op2);
                        op2 = null;
                        flag = true;
                    }
                    operacao = (a, b) => a - b;
                    txt.Text = op1.ToString() + "-";
                    break;
                case '*':
                    if (op2 == null) flag = !flag;
                    else if (operacao != null)
                    {
                        op1 = operacao(op1, op2);
                        op2 = null;
                        flag = true;
                    }
                    operacao = (a, b) => a * b;
                    txt.Text = op1.ToString() + "*";
                    break;
                case '/':

                    try
                    {
                        if (op2 == null) flag = !flag;
                        else if (operacao != null)
                        {
                            op1 = operacao(op1, op2);
                            op2 = null;
                            flag = true;

                        }
                        operacao = (a, b) => a / b;
                        txt.Text = op1.ToString() + "/";
                    }
                    catch (Exception x)
                    {

                        txt.Text = x.Message;
                    }

                    break;

                case '√':



                    break;

                case '%':

                    try
                    {
                        if (op2 == null) flag = !flag;
                        else if (operacao != null)
                        {
                            op1 = operacao(op1, op2);
                            op2 = null;
                            flag = true;

                        }
                        operacao = (a, b) => a % b;
                        txt.Text = op1.ToString() + "%";
                    }
                    catch (Exception x)
                    {

                        txt.Text = x.Message;
                    }

                    break;


                case '=':
                    if (operacao != null)
                    {
                        if (op2 != null) rslt = operacao(op1, op2);
                        else rslt = op1;
                        txt.Text = "Resultado -> " + rslt.ToString();
                        flag = false;
                        operacao = null;
                        op1 = op2 = null;

                    }
                    break;

            }//switch

        }//else ch[0] -> not digit

    }
}
```

}

Agora quero colocar a raiz quadrada. Não sei se irei utilizar o `case` para fazer funcionar ou se irei usar outra forma.

Comment: O código está parcial, poste-o por completo.

Comment: Código completo

Comment: Hum, porque não utiliza Math? use comando **Sqrt** (Exemplo Math.Sqrt(9) e resultado 3) é raiz e quadrada é **Pow** (Exemplo: Math.Pow(9, 2) e resultado 81).. Segue a tutorial http://www.dotnetperls.com/math e ate mais!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basta usar a função do .NET [`Sqrt()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.sqrt?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_Math_Sqrt_System_Double_):

```
if (op2 == null) flag = !flag;
else if (operacao != null) {
    op1 = operacao(op1, op2);
    op2 = null;
    flag = true;
}
operacao = (a, b) => (float?)Convert.ToSingle(Math.Sqrt(a));
txt.Text = op1.ToString() + "√";
break;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Algorithm/Sqrt.cs).

Precisei fazer uma [conversão para `float`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.tosingle?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_Convert_ToSingle_System_Double_) para compatibilizar com o tipo utilizado.

Talvez tenha que fazer uma adaptação já que a raiz quadrada só tem um operando.

Outras operações podem ser adicionadas usando fórmulas próprias e funções existentes no .Net na classe [`Math`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0).

Não quis mexer demais, mas o código é bem confuso e duvido que precise de tudo isso para funcionar. Na verdade veja alguns problemas e ele nem funciona direito.

Acredito que a exceção correta ali em outros `cases` seria a [`DivideByZeroException`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dividebyzeroexception?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0). [Não use `Exception` em todo lugar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/30124/101).

Comment: Error 1 No overload for method 'Sqrt' takes 2 arguments dá me este erro s:

Comment: Oops. Fui no automático, esqueci que a raiz só tem um argumento. Editei pra refletir isto. Aí que a calculadora começou ficar complicada e a lógica aplicada não funciona tão bem mais.

Comment: Já tinha experimentado colocar só um argumento mas tenho outros erros : Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'System.Math.Sqrt(double)' has some invalid arguments ; Error 2 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'float?' to 'double'

Comment: Tenta essa última mudança. O problema é que agora tem que ficar contornando com gambiarras para solucionar problema que não existiriam se o código tivesse sido bem arquitetado. Por isso eu comentei sobre isso na resposta. Vai ser um pesadelo mexer nesse código.

Comment: Isto será para começar a aprender a mexer com o C#. Poderei tentar fazer este codigo de novo. Uma opção serei fazer um botão para cada opção em vez de utilizar o case?

Comment: A melhor forma de aprender é estudar o assunto. Sair fazendo as coisas sem muito critério não ajuda muito. Procure um bom livro http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/c%23/info e leia as perguntas existentes aqui no site. Tem bastante coisa legal: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23?sort=votes&pageSize=50