# Raiz quadrada C#

Tags: c#

Boas, 
Após as dicas dos utilizadores decidi melhorar o meu codigo C# da calculadora. 
Penso que esteja mais simples mas tenho um pequeno problema na Raiz quadrada pois tento fazer a conta e o resultado dá-me sempre 0.

```
    private void btn_raiz_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        resutado = Convert.ToSingle(Math.Sqrt(primeiro));

        janela.Text = resutado.ToString();

    }
```

Comment: Oi Chris, só olhando para esse código falta muita informação. Qual o valor de `primeiro`? Onde `resultado` e `janela` foram declarados, quem chama esse evento e quando? Tente criar um [MVCE](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Relacionada: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/136662/calcular-raiz-quadrada-em-c?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Pode ser o tipo das variáveis que você está utilizando.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double primeiro = 2;

        double resutado = Convert.ToSingle(Math.Sqrt(primeiro));

        janela.Text = resutado.ToString();

    }
```

Desenvolvi essa função e funcionou perfeitamente.

Answer (score 0):

Não entendo pra quê esse `Convert.ToSingle`.

Alternativa mais rápida(não testei):

```
private void btn_raiz_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    resutado = (float)Math.Sqrt(primeiro); //A variável "resultado" está declarada como float? Se não, vai dar problema...
    janela.Text = resutado.ToString();
}
```