# Dados dois números A e B, cria-se um terceiro C mesclando os dois primeiros de forma alternada?

Tags: java

Dados dois números inteiros A e B, crie um terceiro inteiro C seguindo as seguintes regras:

- O primeiro número de C é o primeiro número de A;
- O segundo número de C é o primeiro número de B;
- O terceiro número de C é o segundo número de A;
- O quarto número de C é o segundo número de B;

Assim sucessivamente…

- Caso os números de A ou B sejam de tamanhos diferentes, completar C com o restante
  dos números do inteiro maior. Ex: A = 10256, B = 512, C deve ser 15012256.
- Caso C seja maior que 1.000.000, retornar -1

**Desenvolva um algoritmo que atenda a todos os requisitos acima.**

Código proposto como resposta:

```
public class ManipulacaoNumerica {

public static void GerarC(String a, String b) {

    if (a != null && b != null) {

        StringBuilder c = new StringBuilder();
        System.out.println("Valores de Entrada: " + a + " - " + b);
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;

        loop: for (; i <= a.length();) {
            System.out.println(i);
            int proxi = i + 1;
            if (proxi <= a.length()) {
                c.append(a.substring(i, proxi)).toString();
            }
            i++;

            for (; j <= b.length();) {
                System.out.println(j);
                int proxj = j + 1;
                if (proxj <= b.length()) {
                    c.append(b.substring(j, proxj)).toString();
                }
                j++;

                continue loop;

            }
        }
        try{
            int valor = Integer.valueOf(c.toString());
            if (valor < 1000000) {
                System.out.println("Valor de Saída: " + c);
            } else {
                valor = -1;
                System.out.println("Número maior que 1.000.000:" + valor);
            }
        }catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            int valor = -1;
            System.out.println("Ocorreu um erro na aplicação: "+ e +" o valor de c é: "+valor);
        }
    }
}

public static void Executa(String a, String b) {

    if(a.length() > b.length()){
        GerarC(a,b);
    }else{
        GerarC(b,a);
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Executa("24", "1999");

}

}
```

Esse código está muito ruim? O que ele pode ser melhorado?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não é que ele esteja muito ruim, mas ele pode ser melhor. Algumas coisas são questão de gosto, outras têm mais relevância. Tem caso que pode ser ruim em uma aplicação mais complexa, mas em algo simples tanto faz se está bem feito ou não.

Olhando por cima me parece mais interessante usar um `for each` do que um `for` para varrer os textos. Mas se é para usar o `for` que pelo menos use do jeito que ele foi pensado e coloque o incremento dentro dele e não no corpo do bloco.

Esse `continue loop;` não parece fazer sentido algum. Na verdade acho desnecessário ter dois laços, embora compreenda porque eles foram criados separados, só que não precisa já que está usando `for`. Pode andar nas duas *strings* simultaneamente no mesmo laço.

Acho um exagero usar `StringBuilder` para tão poucos caracteres. Mas não é errado usar. Em casos maiores eu usaria.

[Capturar `Exception` não costuma ser uma ideia](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/30124/101). Nem sei se há necessidade dessa exceção. Eu prefiro evitar exceções analisando o dado antes que ela ocorra. Tem várias vantagens nisso.

Não vejo necessidade de existir esse `Executa()`. Até o `GerarC()` é questionável, mas pode ser útil. Vou deixar porque pode ter um motivo não descrito na pergunta.

Alguns dirão que é ruim misturar a tela com o cálculo, que seria melhor ter separação de responsabilidades. Claro que depende do objetivo. Dei uma separada, até por isso deixei os métodos separados.

O código não faz estritamente o que está no enunciado. Tem erros de lógica. O enunciado não é bom, não define tudo o que pode ocorrer. Inventei alguma coisa, até para simplificar.

Organizar um pouco mais o código ajuda também.

Eu faria mais ou menos assim:

```
import java.lang.Math;

class ManipulacaoNumerica {
    public static int GerarC(String a, String b) {
        if (a == null || b == null) return -2; //inventei isso, não sei o que deveria fazer
        String c = "";
        int limite = Math.max(a.length(), b.length());
        for (int i = 0; i <= limite; i++) {
            if (i < a.length()) c += a.charAt(i);
            if (i < b.length()) c += b.charAt(i);
        }
        return c.length() > 6 ? -1 : Integer.valueOf(c.toString()); //inventei,é quase isso
    }

    public static void Executa(String a, String b) {
        System.out.println("Valores de Entrada: " + a + " - " + b);
        System.out.println("Valor de Saída: " + GerarC(a, b));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Executa("24", "1999");
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/euU1J5). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/jbqsvkig-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Algorithm/FakeCypher.java).

Comment: Sem palavras para agradecer a análise feita, sinto que quando a gente se perde no meio do caminho é preciso buscar uma luz, e este é um ótimo lugar para encontrar o caminho certo novamente.