# Como mostrar mensagem de erro?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, funções, exceção

Estou desenvolvendo um cadastro em C# no Visual Studio e criei um método para incluir um novo registro no banco de dados.

O método é o seguinte:

```
public static bool Inserir(Usuario pUsuario)
        {
            try
            {
                estoqueDataClassesDataContext oDB = new estoqueDataClassesDataContext();
                oDB.Usuarios.InsertOnSubmit(pUsuario);
                oDB.SubmitChanges();
                oDB.Dispose();
                return 'ok';
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return Exception;
            }
        }
```

e eu chamo ele assim:

```
if (UsuarioDataAccess.Inserir(usuario))
                MessageBox.Show("ok");
            else
                MessageBox.Show("erro");
```

minha dúvida é: ao invés de mostrar a palavra "erro" na tela, quero mostrar qual o erro ocasionou a falha pra que eu possa corrigir.

Comment: Você quer mostrar a mensagem que deu na exceção, ou quer mostrar outra coisa? Aproveite para ler também, já que não entende onde está a fonte do seu problema: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101691/101. Visual Basic mesmo? Ou é VB.Net? Ou na verdade é C#?

Comment: mostrar a mensagem que deu na exceção. é C#, corrigi o post, obrigado

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se quer pegar a exceção em outro ponto do código não capture ela nesse ponto, deixe ela borbulhar para onde precisa pegar. Na verdade esse método nem compila.

```
public static void Inserir(Usuario usuario) {
    using var oDB = new estoqueDataClassesDataContext(); //para fazer o dispose correto
    oDB.Usuarios.InsertOnSubmit(usuario);
    oDB.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Aí você vai usar:

```
try {
    Inserir(usuario);
} catch (AlgumaExcecaoEspecificaAqui ex) { //não capture Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); //você pode caprichar mais.
}
```

Consulte a documentação da exceção que resolveu capturar para ver tudo o que ela tem disponível que você pode mostrar. Estou postando o *link* da [documentação de `Exception`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.exception?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0) aqui, [mas não capture ela](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/30124/101). Veja quais você quer determinar que é útil mostrar como erro.

Se achar que é muito importante capturar a exceção dentro deste método, dá para fazer:

```
public static string Inserir(Usuario usuario) {
    try {
        var oDB = new estoqueDataClassesDataContext();
        oDB.Usuarios.InsertOnSubmit(usuario);
        oDB.SubmitChanges();
    } catch (AlgumaExcecaoEspecificaAqui ex) {
        return ex.Message;
    } finally {
        if (oDB != null) ((IDisposable)oDB).Dispose();
    }
    return "Tudo ocorreu ok";
}
```

Aí você vai usar:

```
MessageBox.Show(Inserir(usuario));
```

Você ainda poderia ter o retorno do booleano e a mensagem se precisar fazer algo diferente:

```
public static bool Inserir(Usuario usuario, out string nensagem) {
    try {
        var oDB = new estoqueDataClassesDataContext();
        oDB.Usuarios.InsertOnSubmit(usuario);
        oDB.SubmitChanges();
    } catch (AlgumaExcecaoEspecificaAqui ex) {
        menssagem = ex.Message;
        return false;
    } finally {
        if (oDB != null) ((IDisposable)oDB).Dispose();
    }
    mensagem = "Tudo ocorreu ok";
    return true;
}
```

Aí você vai usar:

```
string mensagem;
if (Inserir(usuario, out mensagem)) MessageBox.Show(mensagem);
else {
    //faz outra coisa aqui que não seja só mostrar a mensagem, para fazer sentido
}
```

Em C# 7 poderá fazer:

```
public static (bool, string) Inserir(Usuario usuario) {
    try {
        var oDB = new estoqueDataClassesDataContext();
        oDB.Usuarios.InsertOnSubmit(usuario);
        oDB.SubmitChanges();
    } catch (AlgumaExcecaoEspecificaAqui ex) {
        return (false, ex.Message);
    } finally {
        if (oDB != null) {
            ((IDisposable)oDB).Dispose();
        }
    }
    return (true, "Tudo ocorreu ok");
}
```

Aí você vai usar:

```
var (ok, mensagem) = Inserir(usuario); //talvez tenha uma forma mais conveniente
if (ok) MessageBox.Show(mensagem);
else {
    //faz outra coisa aqui que não seja só mostrar a mensagem, para fazer sentido
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/WinForms/ShowError.cs).