# Capturar item de lista pelo index

Tags: java, exceção, lista

Tenho o código:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 99999; i++) {
    minhaLista.get(i + x); //x é int e possui um valor qualquer
}
```

Em algum momento a somatória de `i + x` resulta num valor maior do que o tamanho da lista.

Se executar esse código receberei uma `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Qual é a melhor tratativa para esse caso?

Devo checar em toda iteração se `(i + x) < minhaLista.size()`? Ou devo capturar a `IndexOutOfBoundsException`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A não ser que se tenha um bom motivo para isso, não tem porquê capturar uma  `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, a maioria das exceções nativas do java servem apenas de alerta para o programador sobre problemas que devem ser corrigidos, e não para serem capturadas.

Você mesmo respondeu a pergunta, a solução mais plausível é verificar se a somatória não ultrapassa `minhaLista.size() -1`, isto já resolve o problema sem ter que mexer com capturas desnecessárias, deixando o código mais simples.

Em relação a capturar `RunTimeException`, há uma [outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/30124/28595) aqui no site que explica o porquê se deve evitar e algumas situações que podem ocorrer ao se capturar exceções mais genéricas como esta ou a `Exception`.

Answer (score 1):

Para o seu caso o melhor seria um if antes do minhaLista.get(i + x);

```
for(int i = 0; i < 99999; i++) {
    if((i + x) < minhaLista.size()){
        minhaLista.get(i + x); //x é int e possui um valor qualquer
    }
}
```

Comment: Essa é uma das opções que coloquei na pergunta. A questão é: por que verificar toda iteração ao invés de capturar a `Exception`?

Comment: Uma Exception como o nome já diz e uma exceção, é deve ser tratada como tal, no seu caso amenos que x = 0 a IndexOutOfBoundsException sempre sera lançada.