# Qual é a diferença entre "try{}catch(Exception){}" e "try{}catch{}" em C#?

Tags: c#, .net, exceção, estilo-de-codificação

Eu estava desenvolvendo um código para realizar alguns testes quando me deparei com a instrução `try{}catch{}`, só que o block `catch` não tinha os parênteses com o tipo de exceção dentro.

Refiz a instrução das duas maneiras pra poder ilustrar melhor minha dúvida

Com o tipo de exceção no bloco `catch`:

```
object obj = null;
        
try 
{
    int i = (int) obj;  
}
catch (Exception) 
{
    Console.WriteLine("error 1");
}
```

Sem a exceção no bloco `catch`:

```
object obj = null;
        
try 
{
    int i = (int) obj;  
}
catch 
{
    Console.WriteLine("error 2");
}
```

Então qual é a diferença entre essas instruções durante a execução do meu programa? E qual delas é mais vantajosa usar em cada caso e em quais casos eu devo usar uma ou a outra?

Comment: Nenhum. Todas as exceções no .NET herdam a classe `System.Exception`. No primeiro exemplo você está recebendo todas as `Exception`, no segundo a mesma coisa, mas de forma não literal no código.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Até o .NET Framework 2.0 o segundo código iria causar um erro de sintaxe. A partir de então, o código de baixo é transcrito para o primeiro código.

Ambos estão fazendo exatamente a mesma coisa, gerenciando todas as possíveis `Exception` que está caindo ali.

Não é uma boa ideia utilizar um `try-catch` sem corpo na exceção. Na verdade eu até prefiro não utilizar esse bloco. Se você está tendo que utilizar um `catch` sem argumentos é porque seu código é pouco semântico e não é limpo.

Além disso, mesmo se quiser capturar uma exceção mas não depurar ela, não tem porque utilizar o `catch (Exception)` sem o nome para o objeto da exceção, estaria fugindo do princípio que é depurar o erro.

Answer (score 2):

No caso desses dois códigos é só que o primeiro precisou mais caracteres para digitar, ou seja, não faz sentido dizer que vai capturar `Exception` explicitamente e não guardar em lugar algum essa captura.

Então o segundo código faz a mesma coisa, apenas captura qualquer exceção que ocorra.

Veja como o mesmo código é gerado pelo compilador:

```
.method private hidebysig static 
    void '<Main>$' (
        string[] args
    ) cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x2050
    // Code size 19 (0x13)
    .maxstack 1
    .entrypoint
    .locals init (
        [0] object obj,
        [1] int32 i
    )

    IL_0000: ldnull
    IL_0001: stloc.0
    .try
    {
        IL_0002: nop
        IL_0003: ldloc.0
        IL_0004: unbox.any [System.Private.CoreLib]System.Int32
        IL_0009: stloc.1
        IL_000a: nop
        IL_000b: leave.s IL_0012
    } // end .try
    catch [System.Private.CoreLib]System.Exception
    {
        IL_000d: pop
        IL_000e: nop
        IL_000f: nop
        IL_0010: leave.s IL_0012
    } // end handler

    // sequence point: hidden
    IL_0012: ret
} // end of method '<Program>$'::'<Main>$'
```

[Explicitamente](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgNAJiDUAfA9gIwFYFMDGwAEa6eAvHgHYCuEEA3ALABQwATgJ54DejePeYZ+MCTwAKfsACUhGj0YBfPNgCGwbAAtRAAQCMAOgCiAD2yYADsDDIyEznKA==) e [implicitamente](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgNAJiDUAfA9gIwFYFMDGwAEa6eAvHgHYCuEEA3HgLABQwATgJ54DeTeveYZfGBJ4AFAOABKQnQaMAvnmwBDYNgAWXeUA=).

Faria muita diferença se tivesse usado:

```
catch (Exception ex)
```

Dessa forma a exceção seria capturada e guardada na variável `ex`, o que permitiria fazer alguma coisa com essa informação. Mas se não usar a variável também não faz diferença, o código final fica igual os anteriores.

Faria mais diferença ainda se tivesse capturado uma exceção mais específica, mesmo que não guardasse ela em algum lugar, porque quase sempre [capturar `Exception` é um erro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/30168/101).

Portanto o `catch` sem anda é o mesmo que dizer que está capturando qualquer exceção que venha no fluxo.